# About C++ Macro polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

How many polymorphism types does C++ have? Can Macro polymorphism be considered as one polymorphism type in C++？

Comment: What is _Macro polymorphism_?? This term is new for me.

Comment: This sounds like a question from a test

Comment: macro polymorphism is a form of polymorphism  in C. Take a look at the last section of this SO answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8194632/434551. Not sure whether that is supported in C++03 or C++11.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of polymorphism from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29):

> In programming languages and type theory, polymorphism (from Greek πολύς, polys, "many, much" and μορφή, morphē, "form, shape") is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types.

In that sense, it makes sense to think of generic functions/operators that one can create using C preprocessor macros as a form of polymorphism.

Comment: As far as I know, this problems controversial in C++ community.

Comment: @lojunren, maybe we will hear from other members of SO on this.

Comment: @R Sahu, it is obscure.