# C Union Polymorphism within Arrays

Tags: arrays, gcc, polymorphism, unions

Given the following:

```
typedef struct{
...
...
} A;

typedef struct{
...
... 
} B;

typedef union __attribute__((transparent_union)) {
    A a;
    B b;
} C;
```

If I declare a function

```
myMethod(C){
...
}
```

The following is legal without explicit casting:

```
A myA;
B myB;

meMethod(myA);
myMethod(myB);
```

(from: "[c unions and polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718150/c-unions-and-polymorphism)")

However, why is the following not allowed:

```
C cArray[2];
c[0]=myA;
c[1]=myB;
```

This gives an incompatible type error without explicit casting. Is there any way to avoid explicit casting?

Comment: Please, edit your question since it is not legal C as it stands. C[2] cArray should be C cArray[2]. Then c[0] and c[1], should be cArray[0] and cArray[1].

Comment: `transparent_union` is only transparent when passing parameters to functions. GCC documentation is very explicit about it.

Comment: You could always just add the .a or .b, but it defeats your purpose right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) states:

> This attribute, attached to a union type definition, indicates that
>   any function parameter having that union type causes calls to that
>   function to be treated in a special way.

In other words, the transparency only applies to function parameters.