# Receive pointer to different structs in different calls as an argument (or something like that)

Tags: c, struct

For example, assume I have something like this:

```
typedef struct one
{
    int data;
    int dogs;
}One;

typedef struct two
{
    int data;
    int birds;
}Two;

typedef struct three
{
    int data;
    int cats;
}Three;

void swapData(???* elem1, ???* elem2) //<- the problem is here
{
    int temp = elem1->data;
    elem1->data = elem2->data;
    elem2->data = temp;
}

int main()
{
    One dog;
    Two bird;
    Three cat;

    dog.data = 1;
    bird.data = 2;
    cat.data = 3;

    swapData(&dog, &cat);
    swapData(&dog, &bird);
    swapData(&bird, &cat);
    return 0;
}
```

What do I have to put in place of the *???* for the function to accept pointers to either *One*, *Two* or *Three* structs as arguments?
I tried *void* but then I can't access the structs' fields...

Comment: All `struct` contain two `ints`..why do you need 3 seperate ones?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you're asking but this is just an example and the core of my question isn't related to that.

Comment: You haven't fully initialized your structures.  You are trading on thin ice (at best — it is probably undefined behaviour) trying store a dog in a structure for cats and a cat in a structure for dogs, which is what you'd be doing if you managed to write the `swapData` function.  If the structures were not all the same size and same basic layout, you're be really hosed.  But why do you need to do species-changes on your pets?  What you're up to is fundamentally misguided, IMNSHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always define the `data` first in each struct, and `data` is always an int, then you can do something like this:

```
void swapData(void* elem1, void* elem2) //<- the problem is here
{
    int* e1 = (int*) elem1;
    int* e2 = (int*) elem2;
    int temp = e1[0];
    e1[0] = e2[0];
    e2[0] = temp;
}
```

the reason this works is because when you pass a void *, you get memory of size `sizeof(One)` or whatever you put in. since the `data` is first, we can just pretend that you passed in an array of integers, and take the first one. If you had a more complicated structure, you could build a struct where the first few elements are the same types as any struct you might pass in. this way you could manipulate multiple objects. that would look something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    char * name;
    ...
} complicated;

typedef struct {
    int data;
    char * name;
    int something_else;
} simple;

typedef struct { // least common denominator
    int data;
    char * name;
} common;

void swap(void * e1, void* e2){
    common* c1 = (common*) e1;
    common* c2 = (common*) e2;
    int tmp = c1->data;
    char * tmpn = c1->name;
    c1->data = c2->data;
    c1->name = c2->name;
    c2->data = tmp;
    c2->name = tmp;
}
```

hope this makes sense.

Comment: Perfect!
The second part covered pretty much my case :)
I had the feeling I should be using void* but I didn't really know how to 'convert' (cast?) the stuff. Now I know, thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, you have ti write 3 separate functions to achieve this...

```
void swapData13(one *elem1, three*elem2) 
{
    int temp = elem1->data;
    elem1->data = elem2->data;
    elem2->data = temp;
}

void swapData12(one *elem1, two*elem2)
{
    int temp = elem1->data;
    elem1->data = elem2->data;
    elem2->data = temp;
}

void swapData23(two *elem1, three*elem2) 
{
    int temp = elem1->data;
    elem1->data = elem2->data;
    elem2->data = temp;
}
```

Also the way you are passing parameter in `main` is wrong...
You can do...

```
swapData13(&dog, &cat);
swapData12(&dog, &bird);
swapData23(&bird, &cat);
```

**Out of curiosity, what do you want to achieve by writing such code?**

Comment: As I said, it's an example.
Ignore the silliness of the code.

Isn't there any way at all to use a single function?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options available. Among them:

- Switch to C++. You can then derive your three structs from a common base struct that includes the `data` member. Or use classes instead of structs and do the same thing. (This isn't as unhelpful as it might sound -- most C compilers these days also compile C++, and switching may be as simple as changing a file extension or compiler flag.)
- Use a single struct containing a union for the second members. That way, you have only one type to deal with.
- Use a single struct without the union and name the second member `animals`.
- Create a struct `Data` that holds the `data` member, and then "piggyback" any other members onto that. That is, make sure that an instance of the `Data` struct is the very first member of `One`, `Two`, and `Three`. Then use type `struct Data *` when you only want to refer to the common part.
- Look into ways to [simulate OO-style polymorphism in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/524033/643383). Warning: it's not pretty.
- Pass a pointer to the `data` member in each struct rather than a pointer to the entire struct.

Here's an example of that last strategy:

```
void swapData(int* data1, int* data2)
{
    int temp = *data1;
    *data1 = *data2;
    *data2 = temp;
}

// call it like this:
swapData(&(dog->data), &(cat->data));
```

Any way you slice it, the `swapData()` function needs to know what it's dealing with. Plain old C doesn't provide inheritance polymorphism, so there's not a straightforward way to create a single base type that encompasses all three of your structs. So, you have to resort to passing just part of a struct, or casting the struct to a simpler type, etc. Since the `data` member is actually the first item in each of the structs, you can use the `swapData()` I provided above but simplify the call a little bit:

```
swapData((int*)dog, (int*)cat);
```

That's sneaky, though, and harder to understand (or maybe easier to misunderstand) even though it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Create another data structure like this:

```
struct typee{
    int ele1;
    int ele2;
}id;
```

While filling elements:

```
id.ele1 = DOGS; // #define DOGS 1
id.ele2 = CATS; // #define CATS 2
```

Function definition:

```
void swapData(void* elem1, void* elem2, struct typee id) //<- addind new argument
{
      //using id, type cast the ele1 and ele2 to theier structures 
      ...

}
```

**My suggestion:**

```
typedef struct generic    //only One structure at all
{
    int data;
    int specie;
}all;

main()
{
    struct generic dog;
    struct generic cat;

    ....   // filling structure elements
    swapData(&dog, &cat);
    ...
}
```

Function definition:

```
void swapData(struct generic * elem1, struct generic* elem2)
{
    int temp = elem1->data;
    elem1->data = elem2->data;
    elem2->data = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear I dont understand exact need of this, But if there are only 3 cases, then you can encode them something like this,

```
void swapData(void* elem1,  void* elem2, int type) 
{
    if( type == 0 )         //type == 0 corresponds to comparison of One & Two
    {
        One *e1 = (One*)elem1;
        Two *e2 = (Two*)elem2;
        int temp = e1->data;
        e1->data = e2->data;
        e2->data = temp;
    }
    else if(type == 1)      //type == 1 corresponds to comparison of One & Three
    {
        One *e1 = (One*)elem1;
        Three *e2 = (Three*)elem2;
        int temp = e1->data;
        e1->data = e2->data;
        e2->data = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        //type == 2 corresponds to comparison of Two & Three
    }

}
```

Call from the main function using third argument

```
swapData(&dog,&bird,0);
```

This method is not that efficient for higher cases