# What is the technical term for this type of interface?

Tags: c, interface

I work with embedded software and have encountered (as well as copied from this model) an interface I never learned about in college (new grad). It allows a code base to make a `library` `function` call without knowing what `library` is compiled with it, assuming they both have the same `function`. The example below only shows a radio1, but assume there is a radio2, radio3, etc that is handled via the `makefile`.

In a compiled `library` we do the following. In a .c source file, the `function` declarations and the interface `struct`:

```
// function bodies that do things
void radio1_init_radio(void) {}
void radio1_calibrate_radio(void) {} 

// populate global tune interface
const struct tune_if_t tune_if =
{
    .init_radio        = radio1_init_radio,
    .calibrate_radio   = radio1_calibrate_radio
}
```

Then, in a .h I specify the `function pointers`:

```
struct tune_if_t
{
    void (*init_radio)      (void);
    void (*calibrate_radio) (void);
};

extern const struct tune_if_t tune_if;
```

This allows the system outside of the library to call a `function` without knowing which radio library is compiled and linked with it:

```
int main( void )
{
    // interface calls
    tune_if.init_radio();
    tune_if.calibrate_radio();

    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

- Is there a technical term for this? It's kind of hard for me to explain to another engineer quickly at the moment.
- Is this the best approach to accomplishing this type of behavior?
- Are there any issues with this approach?

Comment: I would call it a compile time "plugin". Not sure if that is the best name for it.

Comment: The method is called *object-oriented programming*. The struct that holds function pointers is sometimes called *vtable* (from "virtual table"). Normally each such function should get a "context" parameter that points to *instance data*, but in your case they seemingly use some kind of static instance data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it has a more specific name in C, but it's a form of [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/524056/371739). It's related to inheritance and virtual functions in C++.

Comment: Good catch. I guess I never realized I was emulating some OOP in C. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Note: To long for a comment, but not really an answer to the question.</sub>

When you say "library", do you mean e.g. a static or dynamic library that you link to at built-time? Or just a source file whose object file you link to at build-time? Either way I recommend you don't use a global variable for the structure, instead I suggest you have a specially named function which takes a pointer to the `tune_if_t` structure as argument and fills it in. If all users of the "library" will use the same functions then have the structure be a static structure inside the function, and just copy it.

This way it's easier to have the function take some extra argument and the "library" can at run-time decide which functions it should use. This way will also make it easier to make the library a dynamic loadable module, where different processes can, at run-time, load your library.

Comment: By "library" I mean a static library that is linked at build-time. But the library is also a series of custom-built source/header files, so perhaps "library" is being used loosely here..

Basically the structure is a common "base" that is supported by one of many libraries. At compile time my makefile calls the makefile of the library I specify, and then that library is then linked at compile time with the "common base" I mentioned before.

Thanks for the recommendation by the way!

Answer (score 1):

To me this looks very similar to [plug-ins](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/08/24/plugins-in-c). The difference is that with plug-ins application selects library at run-time, while here you link it statically, so you need to select implementation at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing but function pointers (init_radio and calibrate_radio).[Also called call-back mechanism]

You must be confused with .operator inside the structure. It is a GNU style and tells the compiler to assign address of function radio1_init_radio to function pointer init_radio  & address of function radio1_calibrate_radio to calibrate_radio function pointer

And yes, it is how polymorphism is implemented in C