# How encapsulate structures instantiation?

Tags: c

My question arises from the answer provided in this thread

[How can I simulate OO-style polymorphism in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524033/how-can-i-simulate-oo-style-polymorphism-in-c)

Where it is mentioned:

> You should also encapsulate structures instantiation and
>   initialisation in functions (this is equivalent to a C++ constructor)
>   and deletion (destructor in C++).

To what it refers with **encapsulate structures instantiation**? How can I do it?

Comment: This term sounds a bit ambiguous to me, I think you should ask them by leaving a comment under their answer. But I assume it means "to hide malloc() call into a function". For example, fopen() does it. (It works especially well with opaque pointers.)