# Calling base function from derived

Tags: c, polymorphism

I took this tutorial example [Inheritance and Polymorphism in C](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108830/Inheritance-and-Polymorphism-in-C) and because I've customized it for my exact requirements it's throwing an error when I try to call base function.

**Question: Why does it fail in line 8 of employee.c and Possible resolution**

```
((Employee *)self)->super.display(self); // Sementation fault: 11
```

[Download Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xfwm56pi1kxouce/Polymorphism.zip?dl=0)

**main.c**

```
#include "person.h"
#include "employee.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    Person* person = newPerson("John Doe");
    Employee* employee = newEmployee("Jane Doe", "Acme", 40000);

    person->display(person); // displaying Person object
    puts("------");
    employee->display((Person*)employee); // displaying employee info

    return 0;
}
```

**Person.h**

```
#ifndef _PERSON_H
#define _PERSON_H

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person Person;
struct Person {
    char* name;
    void (*display)(Person*);
};

Person* newPerson(char* name);

#endif
```

**Person.c**

```
#include "person.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void display(Person* const self) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", self->name);
}

Person* newPerson(char* name) {
    Person* person = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    person->name = name;
    person->display = display;
    return person;
}
```

**Employee.h**

```
#include "person.h"

typedef struct Employee Employee;
struct Employee {
    Person super;
    char* company;
    int salary;
    void (*display)(Person*);
};

Employee* newEmployee(char* name, char* company, int salary);
```

**Employee.c**

```
#include "employee.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void display(Person* const self) {
    puts(((Employee*)self)->super.name); // works
//    ((Employee *)self)->super.display(self); // Sementation fault: 11
    printf("Company: %s\n", ((Employee *)self)->company);
    printf("Salary: %d\n", ((Employee*)self)->salary);
}

Employee* newEmployee(char* name, char* company, int salary) {
    Employee* employee = malloc(sizeof(Employee));

    employee->super.name = name;

    employee->company = company;
    employee->salary = salary;
    employee->display = display;

    return employee;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I would guess it might have to do with the fact that you declared the base class as a pointer. Change the definition of `Person` in the `Employee` class to `Person Person;`

Comment: Furthermore, in your definition of `newEmployee`, you are not returning the employee, but rather the `Person` pointer. Also why does your `Person` class need to know about it's derived subclass? I'm quite sure this is violating some rules of subclassing

Comment: @smac89 No compiler magic available, one should somehow differentiate between polymorphic and non-polymorphic types. In this implementation, `void *derived` is used instead of vtab to provide extra derived class specific-state for virtual methods.

Comment: @smac89 please review my answer, and see the caveat for `void *dervied`

Comment: Identifiers like `_Person` which start with an underscore then a capital letter are reserved in all contexts. Use something like `Person_` or `s_Person` instead.  You don't need to `typedef` the names `Person` and `Employee` twice.  Just `typedef struct Person_ Person; struct Person_ { ... };` would be good.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks for your input, I've completely revamped based on your suggestion, hope it meets the standards now. Can you also help me solve the error in employee.c. line #7. Project download -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/xfwm56pi1kxouce/Polymorphism.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks all for the help, I was able to solve the issue, it was null pointer issue to the display function of the embedded structure (see my answer). Can someone upvote the question, not sure why it was down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because embedded struct in Employee didn't have display function pointer initialized and pointed to a function

```
struct Employee {
    Person super;
    ...
 }
```

**Solution:** Change the embedded structure Person to pointer type and call newPerson for super

**employee.h**

```
typedef struct Employee Employee;
struct Employee {
    Person *super; // change this pointer type
    char* company;
    int salary;
    void (*display)(Person*);
};

Employee* newEmployee(char* name, char* company, int salary);
```

**employee.c**

```
static void display(Person* const self) {
    ((Employee*)self)->super->display(((Employee*)self)->super);

    printf("Company: %s\n", ((Employee *)self)->company);
    printf("Salary: %d\n", ((Employee*)self)->salary);
}

Employee* newEmployee(char* name, char* company, int salary) {
    Employee* employee = malloc(sizeof(Employee));

    employee->super = newPerson(name); // call constructor here

    employee->company = company;
    employee->salary = salary;
    employee->display = display;

    return employee;
}
```

Comment: display() in subclass has a different signature, it's not virtual anymore.

Comment: @bipll good observation. It sorts of solves the problem, now the question is, do I really need it to have same signature, I'm thinking about the use case.

Comment: please also have a look at `void* derived` dilemma in person.c, it looks like some weird compiler magic to me.

Comment: I've worked out to make virtual, I'm going to change the whole answer but `void *` dilemma still exists. Update: Code updated, now function have the same signature.

Comment: You're casting a pointer to struct to a pointer to quite a different struct. If you wanted to inverse the compositions specifying super-sub relation, your Employee shoud start with `Person super`, not with a poiter-to-Person.

Comment: Once again. `return (Person *)employee` returns garbage.

Comment: *Employee shoud start with Person super* -> I understand that's the norm, but I like to keep all pointers instead of using a mix of -> and dot . operator. Sorry didn't get you on the garbage return?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, for every class in the chain, starting with the base Person, you should make method implementations available under separate names:

**Person.h**

```
typedef struct _Person Person;
typedef struct _Person {
    void* derived; 
    char* first;
    char* last;
    void (*display)(Person*);
} Person;

Person* newPerson(char* first, char* last);
void Person_display(Person *);    // analogous to Person::display in C++
```

**Person.c**

```
Person* newPerson(char* first, char* last) {
    Person* person = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    person->derived = person; // pointing to itself
    person->first = first;
    person->last = last;
    person->display = Person_display; // Initializing interface for access to functions
    return person;
}
```

**Employee.h**

```
void Employee_display(Person const *);    // available to lower subclasses
```

And in **Employee.c**

```
static void display(Person* const self) {
    Person_display(self);    // calling the superclass implementation
    Employee *employee = self->derived;
    printf("Company: %s\n", employee->company);
    printf("Salary: %d\n", employee->salary);
}

Person* newEmployee(char* first, char* last, char* company, int salary) {
    Person* person = newPerson(first, last);    // calling base class constructor
    Employee* employee = malloc(sizeof(Employee));

    person->derived = employee; // pointing to derived object

    employee->company = company; // initialising derived class members
    employee->salary = salary;

    person->display = Employee_display; // Changing base class interface to access derived class functions
    return person;
}
```

Note that this is consistent with usual C++ virtual method contracts: calling display() from the base class ctor resolves to the base class's implementation and the derived class's method is only available *after* the base class subobject has been fully constructed.

Comment: I just don't want to have exposed methods in header files and prefix them, for instance -> `Person_display`. The idea is to embed the data and methods within the struct. How can we make it work if methods stay inside the structs.

Comment: the maximum allowed by design is to have the new based constructor exposed.

Comment: why `self->display(self);` in my employee.c can't work? I can even add `super` to Employee class to be able to access parent object, will that help?

Comment: Can you please review my answer? Please also have a look at `void *derived` issue. Please download and run the project (link in my answer) for a successful run, then comment line 8 in person.h and see it fails.

Comment: You'd rather store the base class implementation in a separate pointer (e.g. as an additional Employee member). In newPerson you initialize display to the basic implementation, in newEmployee you rebind it to Employee::display while memorizing the old value so that Employee::display can call it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently trying to do is this.

First, you define a 'parent' structure:

```
typedef struct _Person {
    void* derived;
    char* first;
    char* last;
    void (*display)(Person*);
} Person;
```

Next, you define a 'derived' structure:

```
typedef struct _Employee {
    Person* super;
    char* company;
    int salary;
    void (*display)(Person*);
} Employee;
```

And finally you cast one type to the other:

```
return (Person*)employee;
```

which is wrong. It takes memory allocated for the Employee struct and tries to interpret it as Person. In other words, regards `super` as `derived`, `company` as `first` and bit pattern in `salary` as `last`. I hope you realize that's not quite what you meant.

The `Person` subobject of your `Employee` is actually pointed-to by `super`. Of course you can return `employee->super` from `newEmployee()`, this will be a correct instance of `Person`, but this is really a `Person`, a concrete instance of `Person`. It's not polymorphic anymore, and the employee-specific part of the object will then be lost, unrecoverable, unreachable and leaked — there's no way to downcast Person to Employee.

You have two options.

1. Change the declaration of `struct _Employee` to

`typedef struct _Employee {
    Person super;`

This way you have immediate up- and downcasts (simply cast `Employee *` to `Person *`, and vice versa). All the Person properties of an Employee will then be accessible via its `super`: `employee->super.display = display` (where the display being assigned is that static procedure defined in **Employee.c**; to access Employee-specific portion of the object, it needs to downcast it to Person).

The obvious caveat to this approach is some loss of type safety (given a pointer to Person you cannot tell whether it is a Person or an Employee; this can be worked around by explicitly defining a concrete type descriptor in the base class:

```
struct _Person {
    enum { PERSON, EMPLOYEE, STRANGER, UNDERCOVER_AGENT } concreteClass;
```

Now you have a run-time type information, but you have limited the allowed set of subclasses to your Person which is not how polymorphic types are commonly implemented.)

2. Stick to the original design with `void *derived` pointing to concrete subclass-specific part of the object.

As a side note, your original idea with `derived` pointing to the struct itself in case it is an instance of `Person` is a rather elegant way to distinguish instantiable base classes from those abstract :) : by convention, abstract class's constructor sets `derived` to `NULL` and leaves it to the derived class's ctor to set that to proper value; and each virtual method first checks whether it is non-NULL and throws an exception otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood the losing information with the downcast. I've revamped my question based on the learning. If you can please help me solve line #8 issue in employee.c I'd accept your answer. Download project if you will. https://www.dropbox.com/s/xfwm56pi1kxouce/Polymorphism.zip?dl=0

Comment: I've been pondering on your comment that each `display` function signature has to be same for it to be virtual, but do I need it to be virtual?

Comment: I've adopted the same signature, now display function is virtual across both Person and Employee. Thanks for the valuable learning, I highly appreciate your input.