# Why do oop languages provide better polymorphism with compared of c approach?

Tags: c, oop, polymorphism

I am reading the [Clean Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134494164) by Robert C. Martin and having trouble understanding of polymorphism concept.

As known there was some approaches to achieve polymorphic behavior at the before-OOP era. For e.g. for C (this was discussed in the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524033/how-can-i-simulate-oo-style-polymorphism-in-c), but I am following to the (simplified) book examples):

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    int c = getchar(); // read from the standard STDIN
}

// console.c
#include "file.h" //defines struct FILE type with 5 pointers to functions for every device driver: open, close, read, write, seek

// ... implementation of 5 functions specific for console driver here
struct FILE console = { open, close, read, write, seek }; // FILE variable with pointers to functions
```

If `STDIN` is defined as `FILE*` and points to `console` then  `getchar()` can be implemented as

```
extern struct FILE* STDIN;
int getchar() {
    return STDIN->read();
}
```

I understand this concept of polymorphic behavior of getchar (the `STDIN` can point to different variables of `FILE` at the different time - `getchar()` knows nothing about exact driver device), but is there any difference with OOP languages approach?

- The author mentions that C-approach forces to to follow the convention to initialize a pointer like `STDIN` and it's usually dangerous.

But should we not do the same in the OOP languages like C#?

```
public interface FILE { /* */ }

public static class STDIN 
{
    public static FILE STDINinstance { get; set; } 
}
```

If I not take care about null checking of `STDINinstance` consumer of it (`getchar()`) gets `NullReferenceException`

- What about [DI principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)? Why can we not say the the C module with `getchar()` has dependency on `FILE` abstraction (like OOP-interface)? `getchar()` knows nothing about `console` or other implementation of `FILE`. Does it mean DI is possible in C?
- The main question for me: what's new in modern OOP languages related with polymorphism that was not aviable before?

Comment: Maybe this question is so good that it is hard to answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about language design concepts would be more appropriate for cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: That so-called polymorphysm in C is achieved by doing some tricks which are known as ADT (abstract data type) which is considered a pretty advanced topic and.. let's be honest, pretty awkward. OOP languages have it out of the box

Comment: OOP provides subclassing, which allows building specific classes based on general classes.

Comment: Remember, most languages are inherently equivalent. The differences are in how easy it is to write complex operations. You can do whatever you want in assembly, but you have to spell out so many details that it takes an order of magnitude longer to code and debug.

Comment: So nothing was "not available before", you just had to write it explicitly instead of using something predefined.

Comment: Thank everyone for clarification. I got it now that modern OOP languages is more convenient than C-tricks for using polymorphism. The only thing is still not clear for me is aviable of implementation of DI principle in C. In the one hand the module with `getchar()` function is depended from "abstraction" `FILE`, but `STDIN` is not interface implementation in terms of OOP languages, it's just a poiner to a  struct variable!

Comment: Heh.  You could do a rather horrible implementation of DI using the preprocessor.  E.g., `struct FILE console = DI_CONSOLE`.  Then you can choose the rendering via `#define DI_CONSOLE { open, close, read, write, seek }` or for testing stream maintenance, `#define DI_CONSOLE { dbg_open, dbg_close, read, write, seek }`.

Answer (score 1):

> The main question for me:
>   what's new in modern OOP languages related with polymorphism that was not aviable before?

Early C++ "compilers", converted C++ source code to C code and then compiled as C.  Thus all C++ code was a subset of C.  So little was not available before, it is just a question of difficulty of coding.  Also see [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994398/why-do-oop-languages-provide-better-polymorphism-with-compared-of-c-approach#comment84994392_48994398).

> Why do oop languages provide better polymorphism with compared of c approach?

To use polymorphism in C, requires more error prone coding than newer languages.  It is all about less effort to generate correct code - not is it possible to use some other language.  Other languages often were designed for [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) in mind.  With C, that was not a key design goal.