# Struct Extension in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, compilation

Suppose there are 2 structures defined ad such:

```
typedef struct {
   T x;
   T y;
} A;

typedef struct {
   A a;
   T z;
} B;
```

Can I treat a pointer to structure B as pointer to structure A?

In practice is this reliable/standard/portable/compiler-invariant:

```
B b = {{1,2},3};
A * a = &b;

print(a->x);
print(a->y);
```

Comment: Well, you should be able to reliably cast a `*B` to a `*A` because, as stated in the C99 standard section 6.7.2.1 §13: "A pointer to a
structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.". However, i would argue that `A *a = &(b->a)` is cleaner.

Comment: always try to write clean code that is obviously correct. Only if you are desperately trying to optimise for the last nanosecond of performance you can consider applying tricks like interpreting a struct of one type as a struct of another type

Comment: @4386427 When closing as dupe, don't necessarily leave the oldest one open. Is the accepted answer in the link really better than the one I posted? It doesn't quote anything, it's just a "trust me" answer, with no examples. We should strive to preserve quality, rather than preserving the "fastest gun in the west". I'm obviously partial because I posted an answer, so I will refrain from re-opening.

Comment: @Lundin Well, at the time I closed as a dup I didn't see any significant quality difference between the two Q/A. Both stated that it was legal. Both referenced section 6.7.2.1 of the standard. The difference - as I saw it - was 1) in this Q/A the quote is in the A while it is in the Q in the dup and 2) This Q/A includes a little more of the text from the standard than the dup. As said - I didn't consider that a significant difference. Anyway - I don't mind that someone switched it around so that the other is now closed and this is open.

Comment: @4386427 All good then, long as the content is considered and not the post date.

Comment: @klutt I wonder if there was really anything to fix. See above comment

Comment: @4386427 Possibly, but whatever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C17 6.7.2.1 states this (emphasis mine):

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
> reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a
> structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member** (or if that member is a
> bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), **and vice versa**.

This means that you must "suitably convert" the pointer for the `B b` object into the type of it's first member. This conversion doesn't happen implicitly, you must do this by means of an explicit cast:

```
A * a = (A*)&b;
```

Doing so is well-defined and safe, as per the quoted part above.

Similarly, the compiler is not allowed to assume that a pointer to `A` and a pointer to `B` don't alias. The rule of effective type 6.5.7 ("strict aliasing") gives an exception for this case:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
> ...
>
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members

For example, during optimization a compiler calling the function `void func (B* b)` is not allowed to assume that a external linage variable `extern A a;` defined in some other translation unit was not changed by the function.

Comment: And this is btw how you usually implement OO inheritance in C. If `A` contained a function pointer, any struct with an `A` as its first member might overwrite that function pointer to achieve polymorphism, where `a->func();` would call the inherited method.

Comment: Thanks, I was just exploring options on how to emulate inheritance in C. So the reason you have to explicitly cast the pointer is that it is not guaranteed that the first member of the structure is actually at a 0 offset?

Comment: @FedericoDevigili The first member is guaranteed to be at 0 offset and aligned. However, the compiler cannot implicitly convert between different pointer types in most cases, because the rules for assignment don't allow that. That's why you need to cast.