# Does C support inheritance?

Tags: c, oop, inheritance

Does C support inheritance? If so, is it by using `struct`s since classes are not defined in C?

Comment: No there are doubts that come to your mind sometimes when you read the textbooks.

Comment: Inheritance and other OO features _can_ be simulated in C.

Comment: PSA: please stop adding answers that are just variants of "No, C is not object oriented." This has already been covered in 2010.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it doesn't. C is not an Object-Oriented language. Inheritance is a property of OO languages.

You should try C++. It's OO and supports much more than inheritance.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it does. See http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-05/msg00725.html . See Axel-Tobias Schreiner's book *Object-Oriented Programming with ANSI C*. There's an English translation of it available.

Also, see [Object-orientation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415452/object-orientation-in-c) and [How can Inheritance be modelled using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237266/how-can-inheritance-be-modelled-using-c) .

Comment: Can you add an explanation for the first link? I'm interpreting this as "Yes, you can emulate it, but you really shouldn't." Is that what you were trying to say?

Answer (score 6):

No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Compiler-level support for inheritance in C. Nevertheless, as others have already pointed out, Object Oriented coding does not REQUIRE such support. However, its a lot easier to write OO code in C++.