# Does C have classes?

Tags: c, class

I've been asked to implement a "C program with Classes". Does C have classes, or has there been some kind of misunderstanding?

Comment: See [how-do-you-implement-a-class-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403890/how-do-you-implement-a-class-in-c)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, C doesn't have classes. That said, there are ways of simulating object-oriented programming in C - a quick Google search should yield some useful results.

Answer (score 20):

No, C has no classes per se, only C++ (which started out as "C with classes" back then...). But you can use the standard C library in C++ code, even if it is often not considered good practice (where C++ has its own, higher level constructs, e.g. `cout` vs `printf`).

You can sort of emulate the behaviour of classes, inheritance and virtual functions in C too, but it's not worth the pain.

You should probably buy/get your ex classmate a C programming book :-)

Comment: @Nick, because often (although not always) C++ has its own, higher level, more OO constructs to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

C does not have the formal construct of a class. You can produce modules with module-level data that by your own agreement you will not extern anywhere else, or static data, and write functions to get, set, and otherwise manipulate that data. You can even go to the point of using function pointers to manipulate similar data types as if they were in a class.

However, you won't be protected by class semantics or other rules by the C compiler, because the C compiler does not know about classes. However, structuring your data is quite powerful.

Answer (score 3):

C does not have classes.

But one can approximate a class by using static globals as private class members, and static functions as private member functions. extern members as public. In this case an entire file could be viewed as a class.

Probably this is not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't support classes, but we do have **tricky hacky workaround**. Read entire explanation or simply scroll down to code section.

### struct declaration:

I declared an `struct` with name **class**. Inside, I put uninitialized `function` with type **void**, name **Print** and one parameter **char**.
This will look like `void class.Print(char);`

### struct don't allow initialization inside:

But struct doesn't allow initialization of variables inside. So we will init it outside. We created an a `function` with type of **class**, name **Printer**. It inits that `struct` and return initialized struct which we can easily make use of.

### call the class:

Now we included helper header and declared variable with type `class`, name `printer1`, value `Printer()`. After I called member of class and print string using `printer1.Print("Hello from class function");`

`main.c`

```cpp
#include "helper.h"
void main()
{
    class printer1 = Printer();
    printer1.Print("Hello from class function");
}
```

`helper.h`

```cpp
#include <stdio.h> //imports int printf(...);
void print(const char* text)
{
    printf(text);
}

typedef struct 
{
    void (*Print) (const char*);
} class;

class Printer()
{
    class Printer;
    Printer.Print = &print;
    return Printer;
}
```

**Note:**

- This exact example was compiled and tested successfully with VC and tcc compiler.
- `class` is example name. You can use any other name as well.

Comment: This shows me the errors "expected ';' after struct definition", "missing type in typedef-declaration" and "expected unqualified-id before ')' token", I've tried naming the struct, but didn't help, I am using Dev-C++ 5.11

Comment: `Dev C++` is IDE, whats compiler u use ? May be you did some mistake. This same code without modification works on `Microsoft Visual C++`, `gnu c compiler`, `tiny c compiler`.

Comment: I think defining the name of the struct as 'class' is not really a reusable trick.

Answer (score 2):

A classic case of conflicting requirements, it seems :-)

The terminology of her requirements *CLASS, CONSTRUCTOR, METHOD* are all C++ terminology, while none of them is C terminology (the closest of which would arguably be *STRUCT, INITIALIZATION, FUNCTION*). Your friend **is** confusing something here. I doubt that her teacher is confusing something, though...

Answer (score 2):

C does not have classes, but you can emulate it with structures and pointers to a function. C99 is a little bit (just a bit) based on C++, so it's easy to reproduce classes with C.

Comment: C had structs and function pointers for long time and it was in fact possible to create something like classes. There is no overloading atd variable number of function params though also no portable typechecking. I would not call this easy. You can create either nonportable classes (typeof, container_of) or crippled implementation of classes.

Answer (score 0):

C mostly uses functional/structural programming instead of implementing Object Oriented Programming  as in languages like C++ , Java , Python etc. which use classes . But in few instances we use classes like in:

```c
typedef struct {
    ShapeClass shape;
    float width, height;
}
RectangleClass;
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: But how to put function like `void` inside a `struct` ?

Comment: @GrayProgrammerz ideally it is impossiblen struct can help you in working with related data :

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct
{
    string name;
    string number;
}person;

int main(void){
   person people[0];
   people[0].name="Jose";
   people[0].number="+25417";

   people[1].name="Mbote";
   people[1].number="+254-7926-22515";

    for(int i=0, n=2;i<n;i++){
        if(strcmp(people[i].name,"Joseph")==0){
            printf("Found %s\n",people[i].number);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Not found\n");
    return 1;
}