# Transfer of a hidden data in C

Tags: c, performance

Consider the following situation in a **C** program. We have a set of functions, let the generic one be

```
 void needs_param (void * param, ...);
```

, which depend on the value of some parameter `param`. The argument `param` is computed by a function, e.g.

```
 void compute_param (..., void * param);
```

We would like to hide the details of the `param` (type, size, value, ...) to a caller as much as possible, where the caller is a function that makes use of the functions `compute_param` and `needs_param`. How to implement this most efficiently and thread-safe, if you are free to modify both `needs_param` and `compute_param`?

I have considered and excluded the following possibilities:

**a:** Because we are free to modify `needs_param`, one way to do that would be to pass `gen_param` and its arguments instead of the `param`, and let the `needs_param` compute `param` by itself. But `param` is expensive to compute and it is needed several times as the argument to other functions.

**b:** We could implement `compute_param` as

```
void * compute_param (...) {
    static param_type param = ...
    return &param;
}
```

However, this is not thread-safe, using `openmp` we would have to protect the call

```
#pragama omp critical
{
    void * param = compute_param (...)
}
```

which would severely affect the performance in a threaded program.

**C:** One solution would use malloc/free

```
void compute_param (..., void * param) {
    param = malloc (sizeof (param_type));
    ....
    *param = ...
}
```

which burdens the caller with the freeing of the allocated memory, while being inefficient because of the expensive heap memory.

**d:** Use of `alloca`, e.g.

```
void * param = alloca (param_size);
compute_param (..., param);
...
needs_param (param, ...);
```

, needs the information about the `param` size in the caller space, which we would prefer to hide.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You are sometimes referring to `needs_param` (with s) and sometimes to `need_param` - just an oversight, or are these different things?

Comment: Variants of **c** are very common, but then there is often a pair of `create`/`destroy` functions.

Comment: The `malloc` solution is the idiomatic one. All others leak information to the caller or are not re-entrant.

Comment: @lethal-guitar oversight ... thanks

Comment: I'd also think the `malloc`-solution combined with creation/destruction functions à la `allocate_param` and `free_param` as suggested by @JoachimPileborg would be good.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use a solution known as "opaque pointers". It is for example widely used in the Windows kernel world to hide objects from callers.

You first define a pointer type like `typedef void* pobject;`.

Then, you only manipulate your object that way in your program. A bunch of functions like `pobject create_object()`, `use_object(pobject)` and `free_object(pobject)` use this technique.

To ensure your object can be safely manipulated, add a mutex in the object itself. You can also add as first member, the size of the object to perform a quick check of the nature of the object (has it been manipulated by someone else?).

Then, in the functions, you really define your object like `typedef struct { } object_int, *pobject_int`. And in every function that manipulates it, just cast your opaque pointer from `pobject` to a `pobject_int`.

It indeed forces you to use the heap, but that's the most suitable solution if you don't want to share any information about your object with the callers.

Comment: [Here is one example of opaque type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032015/how-to-implement-a-class-in-c/13032531#13032531), using dynamic memory allocation.