# Different behaviour for malloc(sizeof(struct Node)) vs malloc(sizeof(nodeptr))

Tags: c, pointers, struct, tree

I was trying to allocate memory using malloc, I am not able to understand why I am getting a different result for these two malloc calls.

> The line below gives me wrong result even though with gdb I see the
>   data is getting the correct value assigned.

- nodeptr n = malloc(sizeof(nodeptr));

  Value head->data: '!'
  Value head->eq->data: ''

> And when I do this get the correct result:

- nodeptr n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  Value head->data: 'w'
  Value head->eq->data: 'X'

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487252/whats-the-correct-way-to-malloc-struct-pointer-using-sizeof) post, I think I am doing it correctly.
**In both ways, while allocation I get the same amount of memory, just I see the different results in the end.**

```
typedef struct Node
{
    struct Node *left, *right, *eq;
    char data;
    bool isEnd;
} *nodeptr;

nodeptr newNode(const char c) {
    nodeptr n = malloc(sizeof(nodeptr));
    // nodeptr n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    n->data = c;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->isEnd = false;

    return n;
}

void insert(nodeptr *node, const char *str) {

    if (*node == NULL) {
        *node = newNode(*str);
    }
    nodeptr pCrawl = *node;

    if(pCrawl->data < *str) {
        insert(&pCrawl->right, str);
    } else if (pCrawl->data > *str) {
        insert(&pCrawl->left, str);
    } else {
        if(*(str+1)) {
            insert(&pCrawl->eq, str + 1);
        } else {
            pCrawl->isEnd = true;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    const char* const strs[5]= {
        "w.",
    };
    nodeptr head = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i<1; i++) {
        insert(&head, strs[i]);
    }
    return 0;
    printf("Value head->data: \'%c\'\n", head->data);
    printf("Value head->eq->data: \'%c\'\n", head->eq->data);
}
```

Comment: Note that the `newNode()` function does not initialize the `eq` member of the structure. It should.

Comment: regarding; `nodeptr n = malloc(sizeof(nodeptr));`   This will allocate enough memory for a pointer. (4 or 8 bytes, depending on underlying hardware and certain compiler options)  So writing anything as an offset from that pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: OT:  Do not hide pointers via `typedef`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(nodeptr)` == `sizeof(struct Node*)` != `sizeof(struct Node)` == `sizeof(*nodeptr)`

- `sizeof(nodeptr)` will always be the size of a pointer (like 8 bytes on a 64-bit CPU)
- `sizeof(struct Node)` refers to the struct contents
- `sizeof(*nodeptr)` is equivalent to `sizeof(struct Node)` with the extra dereference operator in there.

The reason it may appear to "work" (not segfault) is that `malloc` suballocates from a larger block of heap memory.  However, the code is writing out-of-bounds of the requested allocation, which can eventually lead to heap corruption or segfaults at some point.

Answer (score 3):

The two different versions aren't allocating the same amount of memory. `sizeof(nodeptr)` is the size of a **pointer** and `sizeof(struct Node)` is the size of your **struct**. These are not the same things and they're not the same size. On my computer these values are **8** and **32**.

You want to use:

```
nodeptr n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

or perhaps:

```
nodeptr n = malloc(sizeof(*n)); // size of the type that n points too
```