# Is hidden declaration possible in a project?

Tags: c, embedded, source-insight

In my project, a structre is being used in several functions.

like this:

```
void function1 (Struct_type1 * pstType1);
```

but when I search for `Struct_type1` 's references, I can't find any. This Structure must be defined somewhere. How to find the definition?

OS- Windows

Edit: I think its difficult to answer this without source code and I can't share that big project here. So, I've changed my question to:

- Is Hidden Declaration possible in an embedded project?

(by hidden I mean no one can see the definition.)

Comment: Search harder. The compiler isn't a magician.

Comment: Is this structure and the functions part of your project, or from some external library?

Comment: I know that. But its not declared in header file. Its somewhat a hidden declaration. but not sure

Comment: In VS it is as easy as Right-click-struct_type1 -> Go To Definition

Comment: @JoachimPileborg part of project.

Comment: As mentioned by @BitTickler VS provides the best support for this. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Then it definitely needs to have a definition somewhere. Or at the very least a *declaration*. Look for all the `typedef` you have in the header files, and also look for the structure itself in the source files. If it's not defined or declared you will get build errors.

Comment: @BitTickler Its not working I've tried this already. Even the `Struct_type1` is not highlited.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yea it need to have definition. But I've tried all tricks to find a reference but no results. thats why I asked this question.

Comment: @SKD: And how are we supposed to help, as we don't even have the source files?

Comment: @SKD it's necessarily declared somewhere. Search through **all** header files of your project. Or is it a Windows/Linux structure. ? What's the name of the structure ?

Comment: Start a grep on everything .h,.c  Go out for the day.

Comment: @MartinJames I have already wasted 4 hours on searching reference before asking here.

Comment: @all Please see my edit

Comment: Alt+click on it, or right-click -> find references/usage ... or perhaps it's 'hidden' by a macro which expands into a proper declaration, which is usual in cross-platform projects.

Comment: maybe some preprocessor voodoo similar to: ``#define MAKE_TYPE(t) typedef struct Struct_##t##tag {} Struct_##t##; \n MAKE_TYPE(type1)``

Comment: ^^ ugh!  I hope not:(

Comment: Other possibility: compiler intrinsic type?

Comment: @BitTickler True, but even in that case, ctl+click  should lead to this macro.

Comment: Have you checked makefile and/or project settings? Maybe is preprocessor symbol which is defined there.

Comment: @user694733 yes i went through `mak` files.

Comment: I hate C and C++ for all this header-file crap.  Every time I experience, or hear about, one of these type-hunts, I want to beat Ritchie and Stroustrup to death with a man page printout.

Comment: @MartinJames That was such a java thing to say... :)

Comment: I hope you find the thing before tonight.  It's 14:25 here ATM and, if you don't find it, I will be unable to sleep.  Your missing typedef is taking over my life:(

Comment: Thanx all for your efforts. Got ans from my seniors. It is actually an open source declaration and is locked in my project.

Comment: @MartinJames sorry brother if you didn't sleep yesteday, I was searching the project and didn't come online after your coment.

Answer (score 5):

> Is Hidden Declaration possible in an embedded project?

If you have access to all source code in the project, then no.

This is only possible in one specific case, and that is when you have an external library for which you don't have the C code, you only have a header file and an object file or lib file (or DLL etc).

For such cases it is possible (and good practice) for the library header to forward-declare an incomplete type in the header, and hide the actual implementation in the C file which you don't have access to.

You would then have something like this in the h file:

```
typedef struct Struct_type1 Struct_type1;
```

The compiler might often do things like this with its own libraries too, if they want to hide away the implementation. One such example is the `FILE` struct.

Comment: I have added the whole `Tree` of my project to Source Insight. There is no file other that that tree. Then is it possible that some of files in the project are not accessible by source-insight?

Comment: And as far as .`o` files are concerned, they are erased while `purge`

Comment: @SKD I have no idea what Source Insight is capable of, but any half-decent IDE out there should be able to find a declaration/definition. Usually there's an menu option to find it if you right click on the type name. I can't think of any IDE on the market which doesn't have this feature. Otherwise, you could always download Codeblocks and dump your whole project there, just for the search feature.

Comment: I can't use any other IDE . Company policy :(

Comment: @SKD I mean just for sanity checking the project, not for developing. Also, doesn't your IDE have an option to text search all files in the project? You can always resort to that.

Comment: Yes it has an option to lookup in all files. but it is  not showing the definition one

Comment: @SKD Then there's just two options left: either the struct is something forward-declared by the compiler and hidden from you, or the project doesn't compile. Be aware that there might be various libs linked to your project through misc compiler settings.

Comment: What does *forward-declared* and *hidden from you* means?

Comment: .. or those functions that reference 'Struct_type1' are not in the build.

Comment: @SKD Forward declaration == declaring an object of incomplete type. It means that they have implemented their library as an opaque type. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032015/how-to-implement-a-class-in-c/13032531#13032531).

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer, but possibly a way to find the answer. Idea: Let compiler help you.

Define the struct yourself, then look at compiler errors like "struct struct_type1 is already defined in... at line ..."

If you get no compiler error in this case, maybe the struct is only forward declared, but not defined.

To explain why this is sometimes done, here a bit of code:

```
// Something.h

struct struct_type1; // Forward declaration.
struct struct_type1 *SomethingInit();
void SomethingDo( struct struct_type1 * context );
```

In code looking like the above, the definition of the struct is hidden inside the implementation. On the outside, it need not be known, how the struct is defined or its size etc, as it is only traded as a pointer to the struct (and never as a value). This technique is used to keep internal types out of public header files and used often by library designers. You can think of it as an opaque handle of sorts.

But then, you still should be able to find the forward declaration, albeit not the definition.

Comment: Heh!  Good plan:)  I knew error-messages were good for something.

Comment: Doesn't work if the struct is incomplete type. At best you'll get a linker error, which is probably not as specific as a compiler error would have been.

Comment: OK, then, what happens if you deliberately corrupt your original declaration?  Change to 'void function1 (Struct_type1z * pstType1);'.  Does the compiler generate any hints with the expected error?

Comment: @SKD augmented answer a bit. (reload..)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but even if it is declared like that, then I must be able to find that declaration.