# How to write virtual function in c?

Tags: c, virtual

In order to follow a prepared design document I want to create virtual function in C. Is there any best practice to do that?
As @imreal suggested we can use function pointers to convert C structures works similar to C++ classes but how can we make sure that virtual base class functions are overrides derived class functions.

In my case I need this feature to follow the documentation but I think it can be also useful when we are converting a C++ code to C. This is required when combining a C++ code with a C code.

Comment: And what would be a purpose of a virtual function in C?

Comment: You could revise the design document.

Comment: Create a struct with function pointers, write a functions to act as constructors to assign different functions to those pointers. Every function takes a self/this pointer to be able to access the data members.

Comment: You mean a virtual method? C doesn't have methods; it doesn't even have classes!

Comment: Use an [object system](https://github.com/CObjectSystem/COS) (it's like answering "use C++" but different!). This question has no meaning without an object system - any way you find to give it meaning just means you defined your own object system instead of using an existing library or language's one.

Comment: UseCplusPlus(); override; (this question is too abstract for C).

Comment: @Leushenko thanks for introducing object system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language does not offer it as a feature but you can achieve the same functionality.

Create a struct with function pointers:

```
typedef struct Base Base_t;
struct Base {
    void (*f1)(Base_t* self);
    void (*f2)(Base_t* self);

    int dat1;
    int dat2;
};
```

Write a functions to act as constructors to assign different functions to those pointers.

```
Base constructor1()
{
    Base l = {func1, func2, 0, 0};
    return l;
}

Base constructor2()
{
    Base l = {func3, func4, 6, 13};
    return l;
}
```

Call the methods:

```
Base a = constructor1();
a.f1(&a);
```

Every function takes a self/this pointer to be able to access the data members.

Live example:

http://ideone.com/LPSd65

Comment: It would be beneficial for readability to use better names...

Comment: At this point, why are you using C instead of C++?

Comment: @Donnie There can be lots of reasons to force/prefer `C` over `C++` and simulating OOP on `C` is the topic of numerous articles, but I'm just answering the OP's question.

Comment: How can I overload base class functions in this way?

Comment: @M.Khd Create different functions constructors create an object with other functions.

Comment: @imreal - I know.  We've all done it too, but it's worth asking the question so that people think about why they're choosing what they're choosing.  I was perhaps a bit to flippant in the way I phrased it.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. 'virtual' is not part of the C vocabulary, neither is 'access level'

Comment: C++ is created by C so there should always be a way to implement C++ features in C.

Comment: @M.Khd, That makes no sense unless you are suggesting making changes to the C compiler.

Comment: @ikegami we can add function pointers to structures to create structures that are similar to classes. So it should also be possible to modify them in a way to create virtual functions too.

Comment: @M.Khd, Never said otherwise. Of course you can write a C (or Perl or VB) program that has the same *effect* as a C++ program, and of course you can *approximate* some C++ features in those languages. But you can't actually give C those features just because C is written in C++.

Comment: @Henri it depends on if you want to print a, so called, "kerstboom" ;)

Answer (score 1):

In C there is no such concept as a 'virtual' function.

Instead I would advise that you look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102508/1347519).

Fundamentally:

- Define a `struct`
- Provide a suite of functions to act upon that `struct`
- If a particular usage requires different functionality, then call a different function

Comment: How does this give you the dynamic behavior of virtual functions?

Comment: It doesn't, because that's not a thing in C. It is possible to emulate it (as in your answer), but then you end up with stuff like `self->func(self, ...)`  which destroys readability.

Comment: Still, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin language support, but you can get the same general functionality of using a default implementation if a special one is missing. Something like this maybe:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct animal {
    const char *name;
    void (*move)(struct animal *);
};

void fly(struct animal *a)
{
    printf("soaring %s\n", a->name);
}

void walk(struct animal *a)
{
    printf("walk %s, walk\n", a->name);
}

void animal_move(struct animal *a)
{
    void (*move)(struct animal *) = a->move ? : walk;
    move(a);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct animal elephant = { .name = "elephant" };
    struct animal bird = { .name = "bird", .move = fly };

    animal_move(&elephant);
    animal_move(&bird);
    return 0;
}
```