# How to deal with functions with same name in C

Tags: c, encapsulation

So i have a header and source file containing an implementation for a vector. I want to use the vector to implement a heap. So I realized that I would want my functions to be specific to the class so I declared each one as static thinking I could do Vector::get(int n, Vector::Vector* vector) but apparently :: is not an operator in C and static just makes things private. Can anyone help me understand how I can make the correct encapsulation and not name all my get functions Heap_get or Vector_get?

Comment: `Vector::get` I'm afraid that isn't valid C code. Please be aware of the differences between C and C++.

Comment: I'm afraid that in C, `Vector_get()` and `Heap_get()` is exactly the way one proceeds.... In C, there is no name mangling as in C++. Naming is fully the responsibility of the programmer.

Comment: For better or worse, using a unique prefix is the most common way of providing context, a namespace in C, if you will.

Comment: If you don't mind being weird and nonstandard, you could create a `struct` of function pointers.

Comment: @AnotherParker That's not entirely unrealistic; It's exactly how C++ vtables and OpenCL ICD are implemented. Each object's first element is a pointer to a function dispatch table, from which the concerned function is invoked with the object pointer as the first argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has namespaces and class specifiers to distinguish between things like that but, in C, names have to be unique.

It's a time honored tradition to simply use a (generally short) prefix for your code and hope you never have to integrate code from someone else that has used the same prefix.

So names like `vecGet()` or `heapCreate()` are *exactly* the way C developers do this.

Now you can *do* [polymorphism in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456685/polymorphism-in-c/4456704#4456704) but it's probably overkill for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ah okay, well if that is that standard. Thank you for all for the quick, helpful responses.

Comment: Well, _defacto_ standard. It's not like ISO _mandates_ you have to do it that way. They _do_ mandate the uniqueness of names however.