# Why C doesnot support inheritance?

Tags: c, inheritance

Why C language doesnot support the concept of inheritance?
How can we implement inheritance in C using nested structures?

Comment: Since C has no objects, why should it implement concepts of on object oriented language?

Comment: downvoters\closers this is a naive but valid question imho.

Comment: this is the concept of oops

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415452

Comment: Q1: C is purely imperative language, not object oriented. Q2: duplicate

Comment: Why do bricks not support house insurance?

Answer (score 3):

This is the concept of oop but you can also implement it in C.

Inheritance and polymorphism are the most powerful features of Object Oriented Programming Languages. With inheritance and polymorphism, we can achieve code reuse.

There are many tricky ways for implementing polymorphism in C.

In C, inheritance can be achieved by maintaining a reference to the base class object in the derived class object. With the help of the base class' instance, we can access the base data members and functions. However, in order to achieve polymorphism, the base class object should be able to access the derived class object’s data. For this, the base class should have access rights to the derived class’ data members.

For implementing the virtual function, the signature of the derived class’ function has to be similar to the base class’ function pointers. That means the derived class function will take the instance of the base class as a parameter. We are maintaining the reference to the derived class in the base class. During function implementation, we can access the actual derived class data from the reference of the derived class.

go through the [very good Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108830/Inheritance-and-Polymorphism-in-C)