# Changing value of a structure from another structure

Tags: c, struct

I have just read [Extending a struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218604/extending-a-struct-in-c) and I don't seem to understand what certain part of the code does. 
Here is his current code:

```
typedef struct A {
  int x;
}A;

typedef struct B {
  A a;
  int d;
}B;

void fn(){
  B *b;
  ((A*)b)->x = 10;
}
```

I wonder, how does `((A*)b)->x = 10;` become the same as `b->a.x = 10;`?

How do you interpret that line of code?

EDIT

What do `(A*)` and `(A*)b` do?

Comment: Please note that `b` must be initialized to point at a valid variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending a struct in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218604/extending-a-struct-in-c)

Comment: The code example is the same word for word and the question is nearly identical, this is nearly certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try visualize how struct `B` is stored in memory you will understand why they are equal.

struct `B` in memory is placed as `a` which is struct `A` followed by member `d` sequentially.

Now when you look at `((A*)b)`, it is strcut `B` casted to struct `A` which has member `x` in memory at zeroth offset.

Below is struct `B` in typical memory layout,

```
+--------------+
|      |       |
|  A   |   d   | 
|      |       |
+--------------+
```

and now if you expand it little more,

```
+--------------+
|      |       |
|  x   |   d   | 
|      |       |
+--------------+
```

Comment: Casting `b` in to struct `A`.

Comment: @Jerry Please read some C tutorial or book. `A` and `A*` are different types. The syntax of the cast expression is a type name inside parentheses. `(A)` is a cast to a different type than `(A*)`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the standard, a pointer to a structure must equal the pointer to the initial member of that structure. In other words, there must be no padding inserted into `struct B` in front of its region dedicated to storing the content of `struct A`. That is why the cast is valid:

[image: Layout of struct B]

> Section 6.7.2.1.13
>
> Within a structure object, the non-bit-ﬁeld members and the units in which bit-ﬁelds reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-ﬁeld, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning

Answer (score 2):

If you check the memory layout of the structure `A` it looks like this

```
+---+
| x |
+---+
```

And if you then compare it to the memory layout of `B` it looks like this:

```
+---+---+
| x | d |
+---+---+
```

When you look at it like that it's easier to see why it works.