# What would be an elegant solution to define a set of different structs which all extend one basic struct?

Tags: c, struct

For example, I have a given struct `X`. And now, I am defining additionally `A`, `B` and `C`. All of them contain the exact same attributes like `X` but contain also additional ones.
I've seen the following question: [Extending a struct in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218604/extending-a-struct-in-c/22218696#22218696)
I don't want to make use of this nested thing, also, I never use `X` itself. It is only a collection of attributes which appear in all other structures.
I was pondering about just defining the content of `X` as macro and use it in the definitions of the other structs. For example:

```
#ifndef
#define X                   \
    char *some_char_arr;    \
    int *some_int_arr;
#endif

struct A { 
    X
    int specific_to_a[10]; 
}

struct B { 
    X
    int specific_to_b[20];
}

struct C { 
    X
    int specific_to_c[30]; 
}
```

Would that be an adequate solution or is there something better? Or is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: So they don't actually "extend" that 'base' at all, just happen to have some of the same member variables?

Comment: @underscore_d yes you could phrase it like that. They only share the "same" member variables. At the end, `A`, `B` and `C` have nothing to do with each other and are used independently.

Comment: Could you have a single struct which includes a union?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a macro like that would compile and work, it is generally considered bad practice due to readability and maintainability concerns.

The way inheritance is typically done in C is with nested structs, like in the linked answer. So you would have:

```
struct Base {
    char *some_char_arr;
    int *some_int_arr;
};

struct A { 
    struct Base base;
    int specific_to_a[10]; 
};
```

If you don't like typing `a.base.some_char_arr` and would rather just type `a.some_char_arr` you can use anonymous structs as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1237302/4454124) (and which is supported by C11).