# How to implement a inheritance class in c?

Tags: c, oop, inheritance

I am new to inheritance and overall opp, I am still learning. But, if anyone can help me get started with my UML Design into code implementation from the image below. I will be thankful for the help. Thanks for the help.

Also, I think my UML design is missing something. Can you check if my UML design is missing anything?

Comment: Why C if you're doing inheritance?

Comment: What? This might come as a bit of a shock but, you are aware that C does not have OOP support, right?

Comment: C doesn't have classes or inheritance. This question makes no sense.

Comment: Consider this PDF https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf

Comment: C++ sorry .....

Comment: This is actually an assignment from your professor? To implement an OO solution using C?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object-orientation in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415452/object-orientation-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

C does not support inheritance or OOP, so you need to implement it yourself.  There are a couple of useful techniques that are helpful

**struct extension**

C guarantees that the first field in a struct will be at offset 0, so you can freely cast between a pointer to a struct and a pointer to the struct's first field.  This allows easy extension of a struct for deriving:

```
struct BaseClass {
       ...whatever
};

struct DerivedClass {
    struct BaseClass base;
    ... derived class additions
};
```

Here you can take a (pointer to) an instance of DerivedClass and cast to `BaseClass *` and it will work.  You can also cast a `BaseClass *` back to a `DerivedClass *` if the pointer is known to point at an actual DervicedClass

**metaclass objects**

You can implement OO dispatch using metaclass structs containing function pointers

```
struct BaseClass;
struct BaseMetaclass {
    void (*method1)(struct BaseClass *);
    int (*method2)(struct BaseClass *, int);
};
struct BaseClass {
    struct BaseMetaclass *isa;
    ....
};
```

Now you can create a single instance of BaseMetaclass used by all instances of BaseClass and call the method via the `isa` pointer.

```
  base_obj->isa->method1(base_obj);
```

Derived classes can use BaseMetaclass directly if they don't need to add any new methods, or can define a `DerivedMetaclass` using struct extension with additional fields.  You can also put any other class-oriented data you like in the metadata objects (a string constant with the name of the class is useful).

Comment: @CareyGregory Yes, using an existing OO language is better than reinventing the wheel, but if you must use C for some reason, then it can be done.

Comment: @ChrisDodd can you show me based of my uml design please? thanks

Comment: @user11703752 the diagram is hardly readable it would be difficult to produce an accurate implementation

Comment: @ChrisDodd _Maybe_ it can be done, but I've never seen a successful implementation of it, and if I ever do I'm confident it will be a contrived mess that costs more to implement and maintain than it's worth. Wrong tool for the job. Simple as that. C++ can be written and maintained by anyone who knows C and it actually supports the things OP wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

In pure C, I've implemented it like this:

```
// in interface.h file
typedef struct st_interface interface_t;
typedef int32_t (*interface_fn)(interface_t *i);

struct st_interface {
     interface_fn fn1;
     interface_fn fn2;
     void* impl;
};

// in interface_impl.h
interface_t* interface_impl_new();

// in interface_impl.c file
typedef struct {
    // impl data
} interface_impl_t;

static int32_t interface_impl_fn1(interface_t* i) {
    interface_impl_t* impl = i->impl;
}

static int32_t interface_impl_fn2(interface_t* i) {
    interface_impl_t* impl = i->impl;
}

interface_t* interface_impl_new() {
     uint8_t* mem = malloc(sizeof(interface_t) + sizeof(interface_impl_t));

     if (mem == NULL) {
          return NULL;
     }

     interface_t* i = (interface_t*) mem;
     interface_impl_t* impl = (interface_impl_t*) (mem + sizeof(interface_t));

     *i = (interface_t) {
         .fn1 = interface_impl_fn1,
         .fn2 = interface_impl_fn2,
         .impl = impl,
     };

     *impl = (interface_impl_t) {
         // init impl
     };

     return i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, is this implementation of my UML design of inheritance of oop?

Comment: The UML diagram is hardly readable, it would be difficult to be accurate, additionally, you would need to do the extra work on your side

Comment: but, is the UML diagram missing any parts to proper way of OOP implementation?