# Is C# a super set of C just like Objective-C and C++?

Tags: c#, c++, c

Is C# a super set of C (like Objective-C and C++)?

I mean, can I write plain C in C#, just like I can do with the other mentioned languages?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29

Comment: C++ is **not** a strict super-set of C; from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) : "One commonly encountered difference is that C allows implicit conversion from void* to other pointer types, but C++ does not. Another common portability issue is that C++ defines many new keywords, such as new and class, that may be used as identifiers (e.g. variable names) in a C program."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can not wirte C code in C# and it is not a superset of C or any other language. Read introduction about C# here http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z1zx9t92.aspx

Answer (score 3):

No, C# just like the java. and they both is the C style language. but not the super set for C. they cannot support C language directly.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't write ANSI C in C#.

Furthermore, C# is not a superset of C; it's a language of its own with a lot on syntax "roots" from C (just like Java syntax is based on C), but a completely different language.

Answer (score 2):

C and C# cannot be compared for subset or superset. C is a different language and c# is a different one.

For some features, you may think so. But it depends upon from what angle you see it.

From language perspective, it is not.