# what is real benefits of OOP over Procedual programming 'IN PHP'?

Tags: php, oop

I could noot understand any benifits in PHP programming.We can have access methods,abstraction,inheritance. But I can't understand the real benefits while programming in OOP.

Comment: This question is too broad. There are entire books written on the subject. For me, the main 'benefit' of OO is to be able to group "things" into self-contained packages in a uniform manner *that supports polymorphism*; but most everything except for polymorphism (which require dispatch look rules) can be 'easily obtained' even in a procedural style. Consider the mysqli procedural vs OO API as an example - both "take" an object to work on. The main difference here is procedural API 'locks onto' the implementing methods.

Comment: Your question is duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552336/oop-vs-functional-programming-vs-procedural)

Comment: All in all,   Easy updation and maintenance,  Easy debugging for finding errors, Better Readability  !

Comment: @user2864740 This is not duplicate ques, I am asking this question for PHP, a Interpreting language

Comment: @Shivinnarayan It doesn't make a difference; OO is OO (or really, *some variation of OO*). C++, PHP, Java, Ruby, JavaScript, SmallTalk, Eiffel.. whatever. But the same 'difference' remains: some form of runtime type polymorphism and some notion of an object 'from a template'. This question is Too Broad (see [the general Wikipedia entries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)). Now, if there is a *specific* question about OO - or the implementation of such - then, such might make a good question.

Comment: @user2864740 This is not what I am looking for...

Comment: As it is written, the answer being 'looked for' is Too Broad. If this is not believed to be the case, please try to make the intent more clear. The ['Help' section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) of the site provides advice on how to write a Good Question; and it explains which questions are Not Suitable for SO, and why. (Since there is already a similar - and arguably Too Broad, albeit possible less Opinion Based - question, then voting for it is as duplicate is also a suitable response.)

Answer (score 2):

Object oriented programming is about organizing code in another way than before. It is an extension of procedural programming, and it is about hiding data (encapsulation) and avoiding a global scope. It is about extending functions by "borrowing" their blueprints without actually affecting the original code (inheritance). And it is about overriding functions without affecting the original code (polymorphism).

A funny thing to think about is that many object oriented programming languages are developed in a pure procedural programming language. PHP for example is developed in C and the object oriented features of PHP is a result of a pure procedural implementation.

Comment: I think you are saying about features of OOP, But I wanted to know that the real benefits of PHP OOP over procedure programming..

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of books written on oop. It will really benefit for those who properly organize their code.
If you have proper oop knowledge,then you will be able do following:

1. **Re-useability**
2. **Inheritance**
3. **Polymorphism**

   Now come to the main point in pure technical way,which will help you more.
4. If you have done a project having design pattern MVC, you have
   noticed: When ever,you make a model or controller you have inherit
   it to base class. That mean, you are getting benefit of Inheritance
   as well as Re-useability as you have not written same code again and
   again.
5. You have once make a connection to database and use in each
   model as well as query execution from the same function.
6. You might
   have some function having different behavior, i mean same name but
   react differently. For example a function can accept different
   number of argument and then return data accordingly (Polymorphism).