# Why not everything is static function in java? Any differences in following two examples?

Tags: java, class

Suppose you has following two classes, first is a Cuboid class, the second one is a class to describe operations.

```
public class Cuboid {
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public Cuboid(double length, double width, double height) {
        super();
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return length * width * height;
    }

    public double getSurfaceArea() {
        return 2 * (length * width + length * height + width * height);
    }
}
```

Why not just using abstract class:

```
public class Cuboid {
    public static double getVolume(double length, double width, double height) {
        return length * width * height;
    }

    public static double getSurfaceArea(double length, double width, double height) {
        return 2 * (length * width + length * height + width * height);
    }
}
```

So If you want to get volume of a box, just use the following code:

```
double boxVolume = Cuboid.getVolume(2.0, 1.0,3.0);
```

And How about the following example to use AWS JAVA SDK?

```
public class CreateVolumeBuilder {
    private AmazonEC2 ec2;
    private int size;
    private String availabilityZone;

    public CreateVolumeBuilder(AmazonEC2 ec2, int size, String availabilityZone) {
        super();
        this.ec2 = ec2;
        this.size = size;
        this.availabilityZone = availabilityZone;
    }

    public static CreateVolumeResult getVolume() {
        CreateVolumeResult createVolumeResult = ec2
                .createVolume(new CreateVolumeRequest().withAvailabilityZone(availabilityZone).withSize(size));
        return createVolumeResult;
    }
}
```

VS

```
public class CreateVolumeBuilder {
    public static CreateVolumeResult getVolume(AmazonEC2 ec2, int size, String availabilityZone) {
        CreateVolumeResult createVolumeResult= ec2.createVolume(new CreateVolumeRequest().withAvailabilityZone(availabilityZone).withSize(size));
        return createVolumeResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use statics if you want to , it all depends on the desing

Comment: Sure, but what if you want to compare two Cuboids?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question simplifies to "Why do Object Oriented Programming when you can write Procedural?"

[OOP vs Functional Programming vs Procedural](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552336/oop-vs-functional-programming-vs-procedural)

Besides that, you now need somewhere to store your `Cuboid` data.  Might as well create a `Cuboid` object anyway, right?

Comment: So if I want to save cuboid data, then I definitely needs the method 1;
If I don't need to save data (Like CreateVolumeBuilder class), then I need the static function?