# python map, list(map), lambda and performance

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming

I've been a procedural programmer for a while now, and just trying to switch my mindset to use functional programming (in Python 3 for now). 
So, instead of writing a for-each loop, I'm trying to grasp the interaction between `map` and `list(map(..))`

Lets say I have a simple `for-in` loop which does some resource heavy computation (which I'll replace with `print` here for the sake of simplicity):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]    
for x in arr:
    print(x)
```

Now, when I try to do the following

```
map(lambda x: print(x), arr)
```

nothing happens, UNTIL, i wrap this in a list and it does my super heavy `print` function:

```
list(map(lambda x: print(x), arr))
```

Why? What am I missing? I understand map returns an iterator which is supposed to save memory instead of just holding the entire list right away. But when is my super heavy `print` function going to be triggered then?

Comment: Okay, I understand those concepts, they're not foreign to me. My question is, why doesn't the function work when I'm not applying the `list` wrapper? Because I have to trigger it through the iterator?

Comment: Yes @OgnjenMišić. `map` is what's commonly know as being _lazy_. It won't do any work  (i.e. call you function to compute any values) unless it _has to_. You can force map to compute a single value using `next`. When you cast the `map` iterator to be a `list` however, you're _forcing_ `map` to compute all of its values and thus call your function.

Comment: Because it does not return you a list of values. It returns the iterator itself. Then you call `next(some_iterator)` on it to consume the next value, one by one. Until all values are consumed. Applying `list` to it will make it for all the values and returns you a list with all the iterator values. Or you can use a for loop

Comment: Okay, tried it out, thanks guys, it's much more clear now. @ChristianDean post your response so I can accept :)

Comment: And to be frank, I was expecting it to work like the JS version of map, but then again now that one also makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why? What am I missing? I understand map returns an iterator which is supposed to save memory instead of just holding the entire list right away. But when is my super heavy `print` function going to be triggered then?

The `map` function is what's commonly known in programmer terminology as *lazy*.  It won't do any work unless it *has to*. This is more broadly known as in functional programming as *[lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)*. Rather than immediately compute any values, the `map` function instead returns what's known as an *[iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols)*. By doing this, it's delegating the job of compute the values it was given *back to you*.

A single value can be computed by the iterator using `next`:

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3]
>>> it = map(lambda x: print(x), arr)
>>> next(it)
1
>>>
```

However, when you casted the map iterator to be a list, you were forcing map to compute *all of its values* and thus call your function:

```
>>> it = map(lambda x: print(x), arr)
>>> list(it)
1
2
3
4
[None, None, None, None]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you have to switch your mindset to use functional programming. One of the key concepts of functional programming is [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), which is the default policy in languages such as [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)).

The purpose of this policy is to save both time and memory, by calculating something only when it is needed. In that sense Python [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) are also close to the functional paradigm.

If you want to execute it as soon as possible, you shouldn't write it in a functional style and fix it with `list()` if you don't care about the results. Using a loop is totally ok.

Comment: Nice answer Louis! This sums up the idea and purpose behind `map` and lazy evaluation nicely. +1

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that using a loop is fine, but then when does one write functional and when procedural? Lets say I have some nested `for` loops, is it fine to just inline them with `list` wrapper and execute one list-map-lambda one after another or to still stick with nesting?

Comment: It real depends @OgnjenMišić. There both valid programming paradigms that each have pros and cons. In the case of your specific example, I'd opt to use nested `for` loops rather than nested `map` calls as it'd generally be faster. Also look into [comprehensions](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) and see the question [_"OOP vs Functional Programming vs Procedural
"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552336/oop-vs-functional-programming-vs-procedural)

Comment: @OgnjenMišić in general, list-comprehensions are preferred over `map` + `lambda` and `filter` + `lambda`, note, list/generator/set/dict comprehensions are more efficient when you want to map *and* filter at the same time. But in Python, you should only go with these constructs when readable, and don't use side-effects inside of them (... like `print`...)