# Python concatenate list 1 [I] with list 2 [i]

Tags: python, list, concatenation

---

I have two list

```
priceI = ['2,', '1,', '3,', '1,']
PirceII = ['49', '99', '19', '09']
```

I want to create a new list

```
Price = ['2,49', '1,99', '3,19', '1,09']
```

How can I realise this? And how can I realise this with Numpy?

I also want to calculate after with these prices, do I need to convert the `,` with a decimal `.` ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For clarification: your first list contains the full dollars/euro/whatever and the second list contains the decimals (cents/whatever) of the price? And you want (in the end) a numpy array with the correct price?

Comment: `Price = [float(m.replace(",", ".")+n) for m,n in zip(priceI, PirceII)]` ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to `zip` both lists and `map` with `list.join`:

```
list(map(''.join, zip(priceI, PirceII)))
# ['2,49', '1,99', '3,19', '1,09']
```

---

To replace the commas with `.` start with:

```
priceI = [i.rstrip(',') for i in priceI]
list(map('.'.join, zip(priceI, PirceII)))
# list(map(float,(map('.'.join, zip(priceI, PirceII))))) # to cast to float
# ['2.49', '1.99', '3.19', '1.09']
```

Comment: do not forget to `str.replace` the comma with a period

Answer (score 2):

zip the 2 list then concatinate them:

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(priceI, PirceII)]
#-->['2,49', '1,99', '3,19', '1,09']
```

Answer (score 1):

[Using map and lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997871/python-map-listmap-lambda-and-performance)

[rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)-Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed.

**Ex.**

```
priceI = ['2,', '1,', '3,', '1,']
PirceII = ['49', '99', '19', '09']
Price = list(map(lambda x, y:float("{}.{}".format(x.rstrip(','),y)), priceI, PirceII))
print(Price)
```

**O/P:**

```
[2.49, 1.99, 3.19, 1.09]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip to loop multiple list

```
 priceI = ['2,', '1,', '3,', '1,']
 PirceII = ['49', '99', '19', '09']
 result=['{}{}'.format(p1,p2) for p1,p2 in zip(priceI,PirceII)]
 print(result)
```

Result is

```
['2,49', '1,99', '3,19', '1,09']
```

and for further use just loop through list and use some split method for future operation

Comment: Thanks! This solution works great. but I still have to replace the , with ,

Answer (score 0):

```
     Price =[priceI[i]+j for i,j in enumerate(PirceII)]
     # Price=['2,49', '1,99', '3,19', '1,09']
```

Comment: please add context. Now your question is likely to be flagged by bots for removal due to pure code.