# Should the caller or callee access object fields? (Java)

Tags: java, spring, oop, design-patterns

I have a Spring web service. When building the `Response`, our `ResponseBuilder` class uses a `Context` object. Every field on `Response` has its own associated business logic and `[Name]FieldBuilder` `Singleton` class, which operates on some information stored in `Context`. We want to avoid `RequestScope` and storing state in these classes in order to prevent Java from instantiating too many objects (we are working with >500tps at this time).

The `Context` object has `Media`, `Campaigns`, `ClientInfo`, etc. Inside each of these internal objects are further fields. Each `Response` field only needs some part of the information stored in `Context`.

From a design perspective, should I pass `Context` as-is to every `FieldBuilder`, and have them unpack it? Or should the unpacking be done in `ResponseBuilder` and the method signatures of the `FieldBuilder` be more specific?

Please let me know if more context is needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think less context is needed (pun intended). The `Context` you've described will exhibit many of the problems of a [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) even if it is a pure data structure without any logic. When so much data is put in one object, the only thing that object can do as the application grows is to grow along with it.

Eventually every method that does have business logic will require the `Context` as an argument. This will result in logic being implemented as functions or procedures, because there is no data to combine with it to create objects (all the data is owned by the `Context`).

You can try to mitigate this effect as you've described, by passing around pieces of the `Context` rather than the complete object. That's a good idea and I would recommend doing that; but it probably won't be [the difference between OOP and procedural programming](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60116769/1371329). Ultimately, the fact that a `Context` owns so much of the data will drive the design of the entire application, whether all the objects are directly aware of the `Context` or not.

The question of caller vs callee accessing argument fields presumes a non-object-oriented paradigm. In OO, objects prefer to act on data they own. So perhaps the best advice I can offer is to step back from the idea that OOP is "good" and any alternative to OOP is "bad". The description here gives a strong impression that this application is not OO. And that's neither good nor bad, but mixing OO design patterns into an application that separates data from logic may not produce the intended results.

You may find inspiration investigating Functional Programming.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful comment. We are indeed doing things in a procedural manner now, and as you've said, it's not necessarily ~bad~. But I guess we could either try to make things object oriented, or we could go the FP route and double down on the procedural nature of our response. 

What exactly do you mean by an application that "separates data from logic" though?

Comment: Additionally, is breaking down the `Context` object into individual objects another path? I feel that it actually is the same difference as passing around pieces of `Context` anyway... So even without a "god object" the problem would still stand.

Comment: Dividing the `Context` into individual data structures will not make it any less procedural, as long as it remains separate from the business logic; but I think every paradigm prefers small cohesive pieces versus the opposite.