# Class usage in Python

Tags: python, oop, class-design, procedural-programming

I write a lot of scripts in Python to analyze and plot experimental data as well as write simple simulations to test how theories fit the data.  The scripts tend to be very procedural; calculate some property, calculate some other property, plot properties, analyze plot...

Rather than just writing a procedure, would there be an benefits of using a Class?  I can bury the actual analysis into functions so I can pass the data to the function and let it do it's thing but the functions are not contained in a Class.

What sort of drawbacks would a Class over come and what would be the purpose of using a Class if it can be written procedurally?

If this has been posted before my apologies, just point me in that direction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using Object Oriented Programming, you will have objects, that have associated functions, that are (should) be the only way to modify its properties (internal variables).

It was common to have functions called `trim_string(string)`, while with a `string` class you could do `string.trim()`. The difference is noticeable mainly when doing big complex modules, where you need to do all you can to minify the coupling between individual components.

There are other concepts that encompass OOP, like inheritance, but the real important thing to know, is that OOP is about making you think about *objects* that have operations and message passing (methods/verbs), instead of thinking in term of operations (functions/verbs) and basic elements (variables)

> [The importance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530741/whats-the-difference-between-a-procedural-program-and-an-object-oriented-program/530930#530930) of the object oriented paradigm is not as much in the language mechanism as it is in the thinking and design process.

Also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530741/whats-the-difference-between-a-procedural-program-and-an-object-oriented-program).

**There is nothing inherently *wrong* about Structured Programming, it's just that *some* problems map better to an Object Oriented design.**

For example you could have in a SP language:

```
#Pseudocode!!!

function talk(dog):
    if dog is aDog:
        print "bark!"
    raise "IS NOT A SUPPORTED ANIMAL!!!"

>>var dog as aDog
>>talk(dog)
"bark!"
>>var cat as aCat
>>talk(cat)
EXCEPTION: IS NOT A SUPPORTED ANIMAL!!!

# Lets add the cat
function talk(animal):
    if animal is aDog:
        print "bark!"
    if animal is aCat:
        print "miau!"
    raise "IS NOT A SUPPORTED ANIMAL!!!"
```

While on an OOP you'd have:

```
class Animal:
     def __init__(self, name="skippy"):
         self.name = name
     def talk(self):
         raise "MUTE ANIMAL"

class Dog(Animal):
     def talk(self):
         print "bark!"

class Cat(Animal):
     def talk(self):
         print "miau!"

>>dog = new Dog()
>>dog.talk()
"bark!"
>>cat = new Cat()
>>cat.talk()
"miau!"
```

You can see that with SP, every animal that you add, you'd have to add another `if` to `talk`, add another variable to store the name of the animal, touch potentially every function in the module, while on OOP, you can consider your class as independent to the rest. When there is a global change, you change the `Animal`, when it's a narrow change, you just have to look at the class definition.

For simple, sequential, and possibly throwaway code, it's ok to use structured programming.

Comment: those are some very angry exceptions

Comment: The user should be punished for doing something wrong. The interface should *hurt* the user. And security is **more important** than usability. In a perfect world, nobody would be able to use anything. http://www.usalyze.com/wp-content/dilbert-200209233.gif http://www.usernomics.com/images/dilbert.gif (didn't find all of the references)

Comment: @voyager I've never seen the syntax `var = new Class()`, at least not in Python. I would use `var = Class()`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BigSharpie the code is not Python, nor it attempts to be. I see how it could be confusing, as the pseudosyntax I chose is too close to Python. I was trying to get the concept of [object instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_lifetime#Object_creation) in there as well.

Answer (score 4):

You don't *need* to use classes in Python - it doesn't force you to do OOP. If you're more comfortable with the functional style, that's fine. I use classes when I want to model some abstraction which has variations, and I want to model those variations using classes. As the word "class" implies, they're useful mainly when the stuff you are working with falls naturally into various classes. When just manipulating large datasets, I've not found an overarching need to follow an OOP paradigm just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 1):

"but the functions are not contained in a Class."

They could be.

```
class Linear( object ):
    a= 2.
    b= 3.
    def calculate( self, somePoint ):
        somePoint['line']= b + somePoint['x']*a

class Exponential( object ):
    a = 1.05
    b = 3.2
    def calculate( self, somePoint ):
        somePoint['exp']= b * somePoint['x']**a

class Mapping( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.funcs = ( Linear(), Exponential() )
    def apply( self, someData ):
        for row in someData:
            for f in self.funcs:
                f.calculate( row )
```

Now your calculations are wrapped in classes.  You can use design patterns like **Delegation**, **Composition** and **Command** to simplify your scripts.

Comment: Possibly.  But it extends easily to create Composable analytic functions that you can configure fairly simply to do a wide variety of common slice/dice/analyze/summarize operations.

Answer (score 1):

OOP lends itself well to complex programs. It's great for capturing the state and behavior of real world concepts and orchestrating the interplay between them. Good OO code is easy to read/understand, protects your data's integrity, and maximizes code reuse. I'd say code reuse is one big advantage to keeping your frequently used calculations in a class.

Answer (score 1):

- Object-oriented programming isn't the solution to every coding problem.
- In Python, functions are objects. You can mix as many objects and functions as you want.
- Modules with functions are already objects with properties.
- If you find yourself passing a lot of the same variables around — *state* — an object is probably better suited. If you have a lot of classes with class methods, or methods that don't use `self` very much, then functions are probably better.