# Object Oriented Programming vs. Procedural Programming

Tags: java, oop, code-snippets, procedural

I'm trying to write two examples of code in java: OOP and procedural, but I can't think of procedural code example. I have one example of an OOP code below. Can someone give me an example of a procedural code and explain a little as to what it does?

OOP example below:

```
Class test {
 public static void main (String args []){ 
       int test = 6;
       if (test == 9){
            System.out.println(“True”);     
   } else {
           System.out.println(“False”);
      }
}
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Interesting enough, the body of your main method is an example of procedural code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Practical Explanation : Can anyone Explain the difference between POPS and OOPS with Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360230/practical-explanation-can-anyone-explain-the-difference-between-pops-and-oops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is designed to be fully object-oriented while C is a procedural language. I suggest looking at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_overview.htm to read about C. Java is not meant to be used for procedural. This is all I can do to help. You need to do some research on the programming paradigms.
[Practical Explanation : Can anyone Explain the difference between POPS and OOPS with Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360230/practical-explanation-can-anyone-explain-the-difference-between-pops-and-oops)

Comment: But Java is not fully object oriented language.