# Object Oriented pattern in C?

Tags: c, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you write object oriented code in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c)

I am writing a large application in C and have heard that prior to the advent of C++ programmers used to implement the "Object Oriented" pattern in C. My question is what is the usual form this pattern takes? and how would I go about implementing such an OOP pattern in a modern C application?

Comment: I hate to do this, but have you even searched? http://www.google.com/search?q=object+oriented+c

Comment: rye there's nothing in the FAQ that says "If an answer can easily be found on google don't ask it here." SO is supposed to be a reference just as much as a question site.

Comment: i did do a search on google prior to asking the Q and i wasn't happy with many of the results. I am also just curious what different patterns there are out there, esp. ones that have been battle tested by veteran programmers and aren't just what some guy thinks might work.

Comment: Hey, links to searches don't work right in comments! I'm off to meta...

Comment: @Spencer Ruport: But you should avoid needless duplicates of things easily found on StackOverflow, as is the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where a C++ object has methods, object-style 'C' takes a struct full of function pointers.  The functions corresponding to a member function have an explicit data argument that takes the place of the implied 'this' pointer.

Subclasses use function-pointer structs of the same type, with different function pointers to indicate overridded methods.

Answer (score 10):

Here are a few helpful links to guides on Object Oriented C:

- **[Object Oriented Programming with C](http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf)** - A very thorough treatment of the subject.
- **[Phil's guide to object-oriented C](http://www.bolthole.com/OO-C-programming.html)** - This is a rather simplistic approach to the subject, imo.
- **[GObject Reference Manual](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gobject/unstable/)** - GObject is used heavily throughout Gnome and GTK+ applications (mostly on Linux) and therefore provides a thorough example of Object Oriented C in the real world.

Comment: Check out [COOP](https://github.com/ShmuelFine/COOP) - it has Classes , Inheritance, Exceptions, Unit Testing, and more - with pure C

Answer (score 2):

I used to simply adopt naming conventions for a structure and associated "methods". 
Each method would begin with e.g. CANDIDATE_ for a candidate object, and be associated with a typedef CANDIDATE { ... }, and be in a file Candidate.c

Comment: This method always worked for me.  Much easier than having a struct of function pointers that needed to all be initialized somewhere.  The downside is that you can't do virtual functions without them...

Answer (score 1):

An additional [link](http://ldeniau.web.cern.ch/ldeniau/html/oopc.html) from someone who wrote several OO frameworks for C.