# Understanding the behavior of C's preprocessor when a macro indirectly expands itself

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

While I was working on a big project full of macro tricks and wizardry, I stumbled upon a bug in which a macro was not expanding properly. The resulting output was "`EXPAND(0)`", but `EXPAND` was defined as "`#define EXPAND(X) X`", so clearly the output should have been "`0`".

"No problem", I thought to myself. "It's probably some silly mistake, there are some nasty macros here, after all, plenty of places to go wrong". As I thought that, I isolated the misbehaving macros into their own project, about 200 lines, and started working on a MWE to pinpoint the problem. 200 lines became 150, which in turn became 100, then 20, 10... To my absolute shock, this was my final MWE:

```
#define EXPAND(X) X
#define PARENTHESIS() ()
#define TEST() EXPAND(0)
   
EXPAND(TEST PARENTHESIS()) // EXPAND(0)
```

*4 lines*.

To add insult to injury, almost any modification to the macros will make them work correctly:

```
#define EXPAND(X) X
#define PARENTHESIS() ()
#define TEST() EXPAND(0)

// Manually replaced PARENTHESIS()
EXPAND(TEST ()) // 0
```

```
#define EXPAND(X) X
#define PARENTHESIS() ()
#define TEST() EXPAND(0)

// Manually replaced TEST()
EXPAND(EXPAND(0)) // 0
```

```
// Set EXPAND to 0 instead of X
#define EXPAND(X) 0
#define PARENTHESIS() ()
#define TEST() EXPAND(0)

EXPAND(TEST PARENTHESIS()) // 0
```

But most importantly, and most oddly, the code below fails in the exact same way:

```
#define EXPAND(X) X
#define PARENTHESIS() ()
#define TEST() EXPAND(0)
   
EXPAND(EXPAND(EXPAND(EXPAND(TEST PARENTHESIS())))) // EXPAND(0)
```

This means the preprocessor is perfectly capable of expanding `EXPAND`, but for some reason, it absolutely refuses to expand it again in the last step.

Now, how I'm going to solve this problem in my actual program is neither here nor there. Although a solution would be nice (i.e. a way to expand the token `EXPAND(TEST PARENTHESIS())` to `0`), the thing I'm most interested in is: why? Why did the C preprocessor come to the conclusion that "`EXPAND(0)`" was the correct expansion in the first case, but not in the other ones?

Although it's easy to find resources on *[what](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html)* the C preprocessor does (and some [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23892243/14656198) that you can do with it), I've yet to find one that explains *how* it does it, and I want to take this opportunity to understand better how the preprocessor does its job and what rules it uses when expanding macros.

So in light of that: What is the reasoning behind the preprocessor's decision to expand the final macro to "`EXPAND(0)`" instead of "`0`"?

---

Edit: After reading Chris Dodd's very detailed, logical and well-put answer, I did what anybody would do in the same situation... try to come up with a counterexample :)

What I concocted was this different 4-liner:

```
#define EXPAND(X) X
#define GLUE(X,Y) X Y
#define MACRO() GLUE(A,B)

EXPAND(GLUE(MACRO, ())) // GLUE(A,B)
```

Now, knowing the fact that [the C preprocessor is not Turing complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136686/is-the-c99-preprocessor-turing-complete), there is no way the above will ever expand to `A B`. If that were the case, `GLUE` would expand `MACRO` and `MACRO` would expand `GLUE`. That would lead to the possibility of unlimited recursion, probably implying Turing Completeness for the Cpp. So sadly for the preprocessor wizards out there, the above macro not expanding is a guarantee.

It failing is not really the problem, the real problem is: Where? Where did the preprocessor decide to stop the expansion?

Analyzing the steps:

- step 1 sees the macro `EXPAND` and scans in argument list `GLUE(MACRO, ())` for `X`
- step 2 recognizes `GLUE(MACRO, ())` as a macro:

  - step 1 (nested) gets `MACRO` and `()` as arguments
  - step 2 scans them but finds no macro
  - step 3 inserts into the macro body yielding: `MACRO ()`
  - step 4 suppresses `GLUE` and scans `MACRO ()` for macros, finding `MACRO`

    - step 1 (nested) gets an empty token sequence for the argument
    - step 2 scans that empty sequence and does nothing
    - step 3 inserts into the macro body `GLUE(A,B)`
    - step 4 scans `GLUE(A,B)` for macros, finding `GLUE`. It is suppressed, however, so it leaves as is.
- so the final value for `X` after step 2 is `GLUE(A,B)` (notice that since we are not in step 4 of `GLUE`, in theory, it is not suppressed anymore)
- step 3 inserts that into the body, giving `GLUE(A,B)`
- step 4 suppresses `EXPAND` and scans `GLUE(A,B)` for more macros, finding `GLUE` (*uuh*)

  - step 1 gets `A` and `B` for the arguments (*oh no*)
  - step 2 does nothing with them
  - step 3 substitutes into the body giving `A B` (*well...*)
  - step 4 scans `A B` for macros, but finds nothing
- the final result is then `A B`

Which would be our dream. Sadly, the macro expands to `GLUE(A,B)`.

So our question is: Why?

Comment: I love this question (and how you've asked it). I ain't gonna submit an answer here, but I am very suspicious of the idea of "recursive" function-like macro resolution. That thing where you expect two macros to product text that looks like another function-like macro and then expect it to be itself evaluated seems like... one too many

Comment: This may fall under §6.10.3.4/p4 which says, *"There are cases where it is not clear whether a replacement is nested or not."* and later concludes with *"Strictly conforming programs are not permitted to depend on such unspecified behavior."*

Comment: @user3386109 Indeed [6.10.3.4](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.10.3.4.html) paints a pretty good picture: *"[...] the resulting preprocessing token sequence is rescanned [...], for more macro names to replace. **If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list [...], it is not replaced**. Furthermore, **if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced**."*...

Comment: *..."**These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer available for further replacement** even if they are later (re)examined in contexts in which that macro name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced."*

Comment: @LuizMartins That would make a pretty decent answer.

Comment: Taking hundreds of lines of code and turning it into an MWE consisting of half a dozen or fewer lines shouldn't be too uncommon.

Answer (score 55):

Macro expansion is a complex process that is really only understandable by understanding the steps that occur.

1. When a macro with arguments is recognized (macro name token followed by `(` token), the following tokens up to the matching `)` are scanned and split (on `,` tokens).  No macro expansion happens while this is happening (so the `,`s and `)` must be present in the input stream directly and cannot be in other macros).
2. Each macro argument whose name appears in the macro body *not* preceeded by `#` or `##` or followed by `##` is "prescanned" for macros to expand -- any macros entirely within the argument will be recursively expanded before substituting into the macro body.
3. The resulting macro argument token streams are substituted into the body of the macro.  Arguments involved in `#` or `##` operations are modified (stringized or pasted) and substituted based on the original parser tokens from step 1 (step 2 does not occur for these).
4. The resulting macro body token stream is scanned again for macros to expand, but ignoring the macro currently being expanded<sup>1</sup>.  At this point further tokens in the input (after what was scanned and parsed in step 1) may be included as part of any macros recognized.

The important thing is that there are TWO DIFFERENT recursive expansions that occur (step 2 and step 4 above) and ONLY the one in step 4 ignores recursive macro expansions of the same macro.  The recursive expansion in step 2 DOES NOT ignore the current macro, so can expand it recursively.

So for your example above, lets see what happens.  For the input

```
EXPAND(TEST PARENTHESIS())
```

- step 1 sees the macro `EXPAND` and scans in argument list `TEST PARENTHESIS()` for `X`
- step 2 does not recognize `TEST` as a macro (no following `(`), but does recognize `PARENTHESIS`:

  - step 1 (nested) gets an empty token sequence for the argument
  - step 2 scans that empty sequence and does nothing
  - step 3 inserts into the macro body `()` yielding just that: `()`
  - step 4 scans `()` for macros and doesn't find any
- so the final value for `X` after step 2 is `TEST ()`
- step 3 inserts that into the body, giving `TEST ()`
- step 4 suppresses `EXPAND` and scans the result of step 3 for more macros, finding `TEST`

  - step 1 gets an empty sequence for the argument
  - step 2 does nothing
  - step 3 substitutes into the body giving `EXPAND(0)`
  - step 4 recursive expands that, suppressing `TEST`.  At this point, both `EXPAND` and `TEST` are suppressed (due to being in the step 4 expansion), so nothing happens

Your other example `EXPAND(TEST())` is different

- step 1 `EXPAND` is recognized as a macro, and `TEST()` is parsed as the argument `X`
- step 2, this stream is recursively parsed.  Note that since this is step 2, `EXPAND` is NOT SUPPRESSED

  - step 1 `TEST` is recognized as a macro with an empty sequence argument
  - step 2 -- nothing (no macros in an empty token sequence)
  - step 3, substituted into the body giving `EXPAND(0)`
  - step 4, `TEST` is suppressed and the result recursively expanded

    - step 1, `EXPAND` is recognized as a macro (remember, at this point only `TEST` is suppressed by step 4 recursion -- `EXPAND` is in the step 2 recursion so is not suppressed) with `0` as its argument
    - step 2, `0` is scanned and nothing happens to it
    - step 3, substitute into the body giving `0`
    - step 4, `0` is scanned again for macros (and again nothing happens)
- step 3, the `0` is substituted as the argument `X` into the body of the first `EXPAND`
- step 4, `0` is scanned again for macros (and again nothing happens)

so the final result here is `0`

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Exactly how this happens appears to vary between implementations.  Some implementations will merely not expand the macro at this point, but might expand it later if a subsequent rescan for another macro sees it again.  Other implementations will 'mark' the token internally so that they don't expand the macro even with subsequent rescans.  Either method can be seen as conforming to the spec, which is unclear on this detail</sub>

Comment: Excellent, especially the explanation of the difference of behavior of `#` and `##`.  When I was reading the OP's question I kept expecting those two to show up - and I was surprised that they didn't!

Comment: Great answer! I tried to "stress test" it and came up with a counter example that I was not capable of explaining with the step by step solution. I've added it as a *new challenger* in an edit to my question.

Comment: @LuizMartins: I'm pretty sure the answer comes down to [6.10.3.4 paragraph 4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.4p4): "There are cases where it is not clear whether a replacement is nested or not... Strictly conforming programs are not permitted to depend on such unspecified behavior." Basically, macro replacement semantics are underspecified. This is a known issue, and trying to pin down the exact semantics is futile.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Indeed, the behaviour above seems to be "unspecified by the standard itself". Thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: @ChrisDodd If you wish you can add the link to 6.10.3.4 and some remarks that example I added is very similar to the one in pararagraph 4, which is undefined behaviour by the standard, and I'll accept back your answer.

Answer (score 13):

For the purposes of this situation, there are three relevant steps in macro replacement:

1. Perform macro replacement on the arguments.
2. Replace the macro with its definition, with parameters replaced with arguments.
3. Rescan the result for further replacement while suppressing the replaced macro name.

In `EXPAND(TEST PARENTHESIS())`:

- Step 1, macro replacement is performed on the argument to `EXPAND`, `TEST PARENTHESIS()`:

  - `TEST` is not followed by parentheses, so it is not interpreted as a macro invocation.
  - `PARENTHESIS()` is a macro invocation, so the three steps are performed: The arguments are empty, so there is no processing for them. Then `PARENTHESIS()` is replaced by `()`. Then `()` is rescanned and no macros are found.
  - Step 1 is done, and we have `EXPAND(TEST ())`. (`TEST ()` is not rescanned because it was not the result of any macro replacement.)
- Step 2, `EXPAND(TEST ())` is replaced with `TEST ()`.
- Step 3, `TEST ()` is rescanned while suppressing `EXPAND`:

  - Step 1, the arguments are empty, so there is no processing for them.
  - Step 2, `TEST ()` is replaced by `EXPAND(0)`.
  - Step 3, `EXPAND(0)` is rescanned, but `EXPAND` is suppressed.

In `EXPAND(TEST ())`:

- Step 1, macro replacement is performed on the argument to `EXPAND`:

  - Step 1, the arguments to `TEST` are empty, so there is no processing.
  - Step 2, `TEST ()` is replaced by `EXPAND(0)`.
  - Step 3, this replacement is rescanned, and `EXPAND(0)` is replaced by `0`.
- Step 2, `EXPAND(TEST ())` has become `EXPAND(0)`, and `EXPAND(0)` is replaced by `0`.
- Step 3, `0` is rescanned for further macros, but there are none.

The other examples in the question follow similarly. It comes down to:

- In `TEST PARENTHESIS()`, the lack of parentheses after `TEST` results in it not being expanded while processing arguments to an enclosing macro invocation.
- Parentheses are put after it when `PARENTHESIS` is expanded, but this is after `TEST` was scanned, and it is not rescanned during processing of the argument.
- After the enclosing macro is replaced, `TEST` is rescanned and is replaced then, but, at this time, the enclosing macro’s name is suppressed.

Answer (score 5):

After reading [Chris Dodd's masterful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66596396/14656198) and spending some time thinking, I think I've wrapped my head around the problem.

If you are using the C preprocessor *like a normal and sane person*, there's really no problem to avoid here. Just don't make macros that mention each other and you'll be fine. If you're dabbling with [the dark arts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784742/what-are-the-lengths-limits-c-preprocessor-as-a-language-creation-tool-where-ca?noredirect=1&lq=1) however, you'll find that it's suprisingly easy to stumble upon the problem above.  So here, I'm going to explain how to avoid it.

Note that I'm not going to explain *why* these happen here (Chris' answer already explains the why *very* well), but I'm going to lay out *where they happen* and *how to solve* them.

---

**The problem may happen when your macro "call" has a postponed/indirect expansion**. What I mean by "indirect" is an expansion that cannot be made right then and there, but only after some concatenation or substitution/replacement. To understand it, let's look at a safe example first:

```
#define EXPAND(MACRO) MACRO
#define MY_MACRO(A, B) A##B

EXPAND(MY_MACRO(1,2)) // 12
```

Here, `MY_MACRO(1,2)` is an *immediate* reference to a macro and has the proper arguments to be expanded as is. Therefore, the preprocessor will expand it *immediately*, before any replacement in `EXPAND`.

Now let's compare it to these examples:

```
#define EXPAND(MACRO, PAREN_ARGS) MACRO PAREN_ARGS
#define MY_MACRO(A, B) A##B

EXPAND(MY_MACRO, (1,2)) // 12
```

```
#define EXPAND(MACRO) MACRO (1,2)
#define MY_MACRO(A, B) A##B

EXPAND(MY_MACRO) // 12
```

Note that the arguments inside `EXPAND` ("`MY_MACRO, (1,2)`" and "`MY_MACRO`") do not "look like a macro". Even though we want them to completely expand by the end, they are not correctly formatted to be expanded *right then and there* in the argument. Although these work fine now, because there's no mutual reference, their expansion will be postponed to after the replacement in `EXPAND`, and that may pose a problem.

**Whenever the macro in your argument cannot be expanded as it is, it can't contain the "callee" at any point in its expansion**.

We can show this by adding mutual reference to the examples above:

```
#define EXPAND(MACRO, PAREN_ARGS) MACRO PAREN_ARGS
// Now MY_MACRO references EXPAND
#define MY_MACRO(A, B) EXPAND(A,B)
// Fails to expand
EXPAND(MY_MACRO, (1,2)) // EXPAND(1,2)
  ^       ^
  |       |
  |    This guy is postponed...
  |
...so it cannot eventually expand to this guy.
```

```
#define EXPAND(MACRO) MACRO (1,2)
// Now MY_MACRO references EXPAND
#define MY_MACRO(A, B) EXPAND(A)
// Fails to expand
EXPAND(MY_MACRO) // EXPAND(1)
  ^       ^
  |       |
  |    This guy is postponed...
  |
...so it cannot eventually expand to this guy.
```

Our example without the indirect expansion on the other hand, is completely safe and evaluates as expected:

```
#define EXPAND(MACRO) MACRO
// Now MY_MACRO references EXPAND
#define MY_MACRO(A, B) EXPAND(A)
// Succeeds
EXPAND(MY_MACRO(1,2)) // 1
  ^       ^
  |       |
  |    This guy can expand right here...
  |
...so it can freely expand to this guy.
```

Since `MY_MACRO(1,2)` is an actual macro, it can be evaluated right then and there, and no problems occur.

If my judgement is correct, you don't have to worry about any previous "callees", only the one that directly has the "postponed macro" as an argument. Neither do you have to worry about the other arguments, as the preprecessor will also try to completely expand them before replacement as well. Furthermore, this does not pose a problem if the complete expansion of the macro is not required.

However, if you want the macro in your argument to expand completely and its expansion is going to be indirect, double check it.

Comment: A wee terminology nag: macros get _expanded_ but never _called_!  You're liable to cause confusion, particularly in the context of a program containing functions - which do get called.

Comment: A simple way to express that could be "The C Preprocessor fully expands each macro definition **once**, then can't  expand *a second time* **dynamic** definitions (dynamic build of a macro by expansion result of its  name followed by expansion result of its args)", don't you think ?

Comment: @Zilog80 I don't that's quite right, as the preprocessor is perfectly capable of expanding a macro definition multiple times, even in nested situations, but **if and only if** that expansion happens directly in the argument (i.e. [in the 2nd step of expansion, instead of the 4th one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66596396/14656198)).

Comment: @LuizMartins I agree expressing that this way could be misleading. Even with 'globally once` as it will mislead for nested expansion. I'll give it more reflection.