# Nested invocations of function-like macros

Tags: c, macros, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor, c99

Consider the following code snippet:

```c
#define FOO() BAR
#define BAR() FOO

FOO()()()
```

The C standard tells us that after argument substitution etc., the preprocessing tokens resulting from a macro invocation are re-scanned for further macro-names, ignoring the name of the macro that generated them (c99, 6.10.3.4p1-2)

Thus, I'd expect the preprocessor to turn the snippet into `BAR()()`, then `FOO()`, and then stop, because the token `FOO` is a result of the macro `FOO`, and isn't recognized as a macro name.

But both GCC and clang give me the result `BAR`, indicating that it is, in fact, expanding one more time. This makes sense only if the invocation of the macro "happens" at the argument list - where the macro name `FOO` is no longer ignored - and not at the macro name itself. This is very unintuitive, and I find no mention of it in the standard. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593868

Comment: Not that similar... The answer to that question is simply "the c preprocessor only performs a single pass"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C preprocessor implements *[Prosser's blue paint algorithm](https://www.spinellis.gr/pubs/jrnl/2006-DDJ-Finessing/html/Spi06j.htm)*.

In the moment when a function symbol is expanded, that symbol is [painted blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painted_blue) and a blue symbol is not expanded again.

To fully understand how CPP works you must google for "blue paint" and read...

Comment: Thank you for this rabbit hole. I followed it, and found the book "The New C Standard - An Economic and Cultural Commentary", which claims that the standard leaves the answer to my question undefined ([book](http://www.coding-guidelines.com/cbook/cbook1_1.pdf), page 1970, "However, given the definitions...").

Comment: @koorkevani The best way to learn how CPP works is by implementing it yourself in your preferred language.  I implemented it in lisp and it takes a few hundred lines of code.  It is not conceptually difficult, and you test your implementation using as input the IOCCC winning code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the relevant passage from the C Standard:

> **6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement**
>
> 1 After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and # and ## processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace.
>
> 2 If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer available for further replacement even if they are later (re)examined in contexts in which that macro name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced.
>
> 3 The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, but all pragma unary operator expressions within it are then processed as specified in 6.10.9 below.

If for example you had written

```
#define QQ() QQ
QQ()()()
```

The expansion would be just `QQ()()` because as per 2) when `QQ` is found during the scan of the replacement list, it is not expanded.

Conversely, in your example, `FOO` is not found in the replacement list of `FOO()`, `BAR` is followed by `()` which causes it to be expanded and in turn `BAR` not found in the replacement list of `BAR()`, but `FOO` followed by the last set of `()` is again expanded.

The phrase *if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced* refers to replacements occurring during expansion of macro arguments. In your example, the replacements occur iteratively, not recursively, hence extra set of `()` will cause further expansion.

Comment: Oh, good.  Now I don't have to write this very same thing.