# Preprocessor macro expansion (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E) §6.10.3.5 EXAMPLE 3)

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

In the C99 standard, example 3 of section 10.3.5 demonstrates macro expansion for f (modified):

```
#define f(a)    f(a)
#define z       z[0]
f(z)
```

The result of expansion is "f(z[0])", which is true also for MSVC and GCC. But I can't figure out why the result is not "f(z[0][0])" as might result from the following sequence of macro expansions:

- during arguments macro expansion, z argument is replaced with z[0]:
  `f(z[0])`
- "f(z[0])" is replaced with "f(z[0])":
  `f(z[0])`
- during rescan, z is replaced with z[0] again:
  `f(z[0][0])`

which obviously differs from the correct result. Both expansions of z are completely separate, so no recursion prevention applies. However, one of z expansions is not performed. Why?

Please help me understand where I'm wrong here

Obviously, all preprocessors produce the correct result, so it's important for me to understand what's really going on here.

Comment: OK, I found a SO page [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593868/understanding-the-behavior-of-cs-preprocessor-when-a-macro-indirectly-expands-i?rq=2) where Chris Dodd's reply says that there are two macro expansions (argments and macro body), which makes things even more unclear.

Comment: After z is expended the first time, it is [marked blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painted_blue)

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for interesting link (6.10.3.4.pdf), but I'm afraid this is not related to the topic of the question. The problem was not with direct or indirect recursion (in which case expansion of z would not have stopped), but with two completely independent expansions of z (the first expansion is performed while processing argument list and the second one when macro body is rescanned). According to Weijun Zhou's reply, the second expansion is not performed if macro is recurrent EVEN IF IT'S SAFE TO EXPAND IT. That's a completely different mechanism.

Comment: https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.4p2 "The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned .... If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list .... it is not replaced" - `f(z)` is replaced by `f(z[0])` and then rescanned. The name `z` is found during this (re-) scan of the replacement list, the name `z` is "beeing replaced" by `z[0]`, so `z` is not replaced during rescan. No? In other words, `z` is "marked blue" the first time it was expanded.

Comment: @KamilCuk But why z is not replaced during rescan? It's not a recursive macro call, just sequential macro invocations during two different steps. First time we get `f(z[0[)` during argument macro expansion, so we get `f(z[0])` as a macro body which is rescanned and z would be replaced for the second time, so we would get `f(z[0][0])`. The quote says "macro being replaced", but it's f that is being replaced, not z.

Comment: @KamilCuk Quote from Weijun Zhou link: "You might expect the double scan to change the results when a self-referential macro is used in an argument of **another macro** (see Self-Referential Macros): the self-referential macro would be **expanded once in the first scan**, and **a second time in the second scan**. However, this is not what happens. The self-references that do not expand in the first scan are marked so that they will not expand in the second scan either." That's the reason z is not expanded for the second time (no recursion prevention rule applies here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see where your confusion comes from. This is not an official source from the standard, but it is from GCC and should be authorative enough to explain what is happening. It has a paragraph that exactly refers to your case here.

> You might expect the double scan to change the results when a
> self-referential macro is used in an argument of another macro (see
> Self-Referential Macros): the self-referential macro would be expanded
> once in the first scan, and a second time in the second scan. However,
> this is not what happens. The self-references that do not expand in
> the first scan are marked so that they will not expand in the second
> scan either.

At the time of writing, this is the third paragraph from https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html

Comment: Thank you, that must be it. It's quite strange behaviour since there is no direct or indirect macro recursion, so it looks unneeded exception. Well now I have to figure out how to implement it without adding hacks.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor replaces tokens.

1. `z` is being replaced by `z[0]`
2. `f(a)` as `a` is `z[0]` it is replaced by `f(z[0])`.

There are no more replacements in those macros as everything was already preprocessed. A single token is processed only one time.

Comment: But shouldn't rescan be performed after expanded argument is substituted to the macro body?

Comment: @mdod no, as the job was done. A single token is processed only one time. You overcomplicating things for yourself. Macro expansion is only a token replacement process.

Comment: But if we modify example slightly, we'll see that rescan is performed for all macros except z. Why z is not expanded?
```#define a(x) N(x)
#define b(x) a(x)
#define c(x) b(x)
#define f(x) c(x)
#define z  z[0]
```

Comment: @mdod the answer is very easy  - you have nested macros.  I think you need to understand what the token is.  when `x` parameter is processed then it recognizes the new token which has to be processed. And this token is also processed only once. **There is no recursion*** in macros