# how to program high level concepts (i.e. Object class, and Generics) in C

Tags: c, programming-languages, assembly

Here lately I've been tinkering around with my own languages as well as reading various writings on the subject.

Does anyone have any good advice on how, in C (or Assembler), do you program the concept of the `Object Class` and/or the concept of `Generics` into a language. (referring to the Java implementations of Object and Generics)

For instance, in Java all all classes extend Object. So how do you represent this at the C level? is it something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int stuff;
} Object;


typedef struct {
  int stuff;
  Object object;
} ChildClass;


int main() {
    ChildClass childClass;
    childClass.stuff = 100;
    childClass.object.stuff = 200;
    printf("%d\n", childClass.stuff);
    printf("%d\n", childClass.object.stuff);
}
```

And I'm not really even sure how to get started with implementing something like Generics.
I also appreciate any valuable links regarding program langauge design.
Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you write object oriented code in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c)

Comment: "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should" ;)

Comment: @Jens My question is not so much as can you, I know you can, considering there are many languages built of of C. It's more of a how do you do it.

Comment: @Delnan, i'm not saying I want to write object oriented code in C hehe, if I wanted to write in OO code I would just use another language that natively implements it. I'm just more interested in how the OO languages were developed to begin with (sorry my Programming Languages class was very lacking)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I learn to implement OOP in C? Are there projects that use OOP in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325306/should-i-learn-to-implement-oop-in-c-are-there-projects-that-use-oop-in-c)

Comment: @Matt That's not my point, I'm not asking if I should learn OOP in C,or if there are projects that use OOP in C. I in fact don't want to program OOP in C, if I want to program OOP i'll use a language that natively supports it. But ALL OOP languages were at some point programmed from a language that doesn't support OOP, so my question is HOW do you program OOP stuff in C or ASM (for the purpose of developing an higher level OOP programming language), and not "should i do it"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this book a little while ago that has been an interesting read: [Object-Oriented Programming With ANSI-C](http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf) (PDF).

In C I've created class-like structures and methods by using `struct`s (to store the class's state) and functions that take pointers to them (methods of the class).  Implementing things like inheritance is possible, but would get messy fast.  I'm not a Java guy though, and I'm not sure how much of Java you should press onto C, they are very different languages.

---

Here's probably the crudest form of a object implementation possible; I wrote it to run multiple PID controls at the same time.

```
//! PID control system state variables
typedef struct {
    const PID_K * K;  //!< PID control parameters
    int32_t e; //!< Previous error (for derivative term)
    int32_t i; //!< Integrator
} PID_SYS;

void PID_Init(PID_SYS * sys, const PID_K * K)
{
    sys->i = 0;
    sys->e = 0;
    sys->K = K;
}

int16_t PID_Step(PID_SYS * sys, int32_t e)
{
    // ...PID math using "sys->" for any persistent state variables...
}
```

Comment: Right, my goal is definitely not to Program a language like Java with C :P, I am in general more interested in just seeing how other people have implemented the high level concepts that we see in modern programming languages. Especially considering most of them were written in C at one point. And even C++ has it's C roots.

Comment: After note: That PDF is very interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262011530) by Abelson and Sussman.  While it doesn't show how to do it in C, it does demonstrate how to create types at run time and how to build an object system on top of a language that doesn't provide native support.  Once you understand the basic ideas, you should be able to use structs and function pointers to create an implementation.  Of course, looking at the source code for a C++ preprocessor will also be instructive.  At one time, C++ was just a preprocessor for a C compiler.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like a very interesting read, I look forward to checking it out.

Comment: I will have to buy it and give it a look myself. @Santiago I think you may find Nick's link (posted above) pretty useful. I've been looking over it for the last few hours and have had many of my questions answered.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to write a new language that incorporates high level concepts, you might want to look at the CPython sources. CPython is an object oriented programming language whose interpreter is written in C. Open source C implementations of compilers/interpreters for C++, D, Javascript, Go, Objective C, and many, many others exist as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'll give them a look, I guess I should have thought to do that in the first place :P though considering the size of the projects I imagine it would still be a tough task

Answer (score 1):

It's more complicated, but you're on the right path. Actual implementations use roughly the same code as yours to achieve inheritance (but they actually use containment to do it, which is quite ironic), along with a per-instance table of function pointers (virtual functions) and some (okay, many) helper macros.

See [gobject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject).

Comment: nice. Thanks, i'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not C, but I'd recommend taking a look at Lua.

At its core, Lua only has a few basic types: number, string, boolean, function, and table (there's a couple more outside of the scope of this topic, though.  A table is essentially just a hashtable that accepts keys of any type and can contain values of any type as well.

You can [implement OOP in Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaClassesWithMetatable) by way of *metatables*.  In Lua, a table is allowed to have up to one metatable, which is accessed [under special circumstances](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetamethodsTutorial), such as when a table is added or multiplied to another table or when you try to access a key that is not present in the table.

Using metatables, you can quickly and easily achieve something quite like inheritance by chaining together multiple metatables.  When you try to access a missing key in a table, Lua looks up a key named `__index` in that table's metatable.  So if you try to access a key named `foo` on a table that doesn't have such a key, Lua will check for `foo` in the first metatable.  If it isn't present there and that metatable has a metatable of its own with `__index` defined, it will check for `foo` in the next one, and so on.

Once you realize how simple it is to do this in Lua, translating it to C is very achievable.  Your OOP will be completely at run-time, of course, but it will be very OOP-like indeed.

Comment: Interesting, actually, when I was imagining how a high level langauge implements inheritance, I thought about something similar, I'll give it a look