# OOP and interfaces in C

Tags: c, oop

Straight of the bat I understand that ANSI C is not an object orientated programming language. I want to learn how to apply a particular oo technique using c.

For example, I want to create several audio effect classes that all have the same function names but different implementations of those functions.

If I was making this in a higher level language I would first write an interface and then implement it.

```
AudioEffectInterface

-(float) processEffect 



DelayClass

-(float) processEffect

{
 // do delay code

  return result

}

FlangerClass

-(float) processEffect

{
 // do flanger code

  return result

}



-(void) main

{
   effect= new DelayEffect()
   effect.process()

   effect = new FlangerEffect()
   effect.process()


}
```

How can I achieve such flexibility using C?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c/351745#351745 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103704/experiment-object-oriented-c/4103725#4103725 for examples.

Answer (score 58):

There are three distinct ways you can achieve polymorphism in C:

1. **Code it out**
   In the base class functions, just `switch` on a class type ID to call the specialized versions. An incomplete code example:

   ```
   typedef enum classType {
       CLASS_A,
       CLASS_B
   } classType;

   typedef struct base {
       classType type;
   } base;

   typedef struct A {
       base super;
       ...
   } A;

   typedef struct B {
       base super;
       ...
   } B;

   void A_construct(A* me) {
       base_construct(&me->super);
       super->type = CLASS_A;
   }

   int base_foo(base* me) {
       switch(me->type) {
           case CLASS_A: return A_foo(me);
           case CLASS_B: return B_foo(me);
           default: assert(0), abort();
       }
   }
   ```

   Of course, this *is* tedious to do for large classes.
2. **Store function pointers in the object**
   You can avoid the switch statements by using a function pointer for each member function. Again, this is incomplete code:

   ```
   typedef struct base {
       int (*foo)(base* me);
   } base;

   //class definitions for A and B as above

   int A_foo(base* me);

   void A_construct(A* me) {
       base_construct(&me->super);
       me->super.foo = A_foo;
   }
   ```

   Now, calling code may just do

   ```
   base* anObject = ...;
   (*anObject->foo)(anObject);
   ```

   Alternatively, you may use a preprocessor macro along the lines of:

   ```
   #define base_foo(me) (*me->foo)(me)
   ```

   Note that this evaluates the expression `me` twice, so this is really a bad idea. This may be fixed, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.
3. **Use a vtable**
   Since all objects of a class share the same set of member functions, they can all use the same function pointers. This is very close to what C++ does under the hood:

   ```
   typedef struct base_vtable {
       int (*foo)(base* me);
       ...
   } base_vtable;

   typedef struct base {
       base_vtable* vtable;
       ...
   } base;

   typedef struct A_vtable {
       base_vtable super;
       ...
   } A_vtable;



   //within A.c

   int A_foo(base* super);
   static A_vtable gVtable = {
       .foo = A_foo,
       ...
   };

   void A_construct(A* me) {
       base_construct(&me->super);
       me->super.vtable = &gVtable;
   };
   ```

   Again, this allows the user code to do the dispatch (with one additional indirection):

   ```
   base* anObject = ...;
   (*anObject->vtable->foo)(anObject);
   ```

Which method you should use depends on the task at hand. The `switch` based approach is easy to whip up for two or three small classes, but is unwieldy for large classes and hierarchies. The second approach scales much better, but has a lot of space overhead due to the duplicated function pointers. The vtable approach requires quite a bit of additional structure and introduces even more indirection (which makes the code harder to read), but is certainly the way to go for complex class hierarchies.

Comment: How can you set base_vtable.foo = A_foo? Presumably A_foo's signature would take an instance of A as a parameter? Wouldn't you at least need to cast somehow?

Comment: @weberc2 Yes, you need a cast. That would usually be the first thing you do within `A_foo()`: `A* me = (A*)super;` You could also cast the function pointen when you assign it (`.foo = (int (*)(base*))A_foo,`, but I think that's more dangerous since it would hide mismatches in other arguments to `A_foo()`.

Comment: Is there a reason A_vtable was created? Couldn't A.c just use the base vtable?

Comment: @Jin Yes: `A_vtable` can add more pointers that are not present in `base_vtable`, and which are different from additional pointers `B_vtable` may define for the use of its own subclasses. Of course, you can move everything into `base_vtable`, but then you might have to set some function pointers to `NULL`. Defining a special vtable structure for each class makes the approach more scalable and keeps the stuff that's related to `A` closer together.

Comment: Would the following be one more approach: if we're talking about a fake implementation for testing, that complies with some interface, can we declare methods in the "my_functions.h" file (so what's in "my_functions.h" becomes an interface), and then the real implementation in "my_functions.c" file, but the fake implementation in "my_fake_functions.c". Link "my_functions.c" in prod code, but "my_fake_functions.c" in the test code.

Comment: @mercury0114 That approach would make the decision of which function to use at compile time. The point of using interfaces, or creating virtual functions in C++ parlance, is to shift the decision to the runtime of the program. Pass in a `base*` that happens to point to an instance of class `A`, and A's methods will be called. Pass in an instance of class `B`, and B's methods will be called. Call `foo()` for each pointer in a list of `base*`, and each call may use a different implementation depending on the object's actual type. This cannot be achieved with compile time tricks.

Comment: @cmaster I agree with what you said: if we want a run-time polymorphism, then using pointers is the right approach. I was just wondering, that maybe depending on a use case, one binary might not need multiple implementations of the same interface (e.g. test binary vs prod binary). In other languages like Java, we would still have an `AudioInterface`, and use `RealAudio` in the production code vs `FakeAudio` in the test code. But would this compile-time approach be a reasonable way to achieve what we want (i.e. to find a way of using a fake method for tests) in C?

Comment: @mercury0114 I'd say that it can be made to work, but I cannot recommend it in any way. For one thing, it means that you would have to produce a number of different test executables because one test will need to mock the class, and another test will need to test the class. With a hand full of classes that mock each other, madness ensues. Likewise, it wouldn't be visible within the test code that it is using a mock implementation at all. That info would be tucked away in the build system, and madness will ensue. I can't say what the "right" approach would be, but this one does not feel like it.

Answer (score 15):

Can you compromise with the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct effect_ops {
    float (*processEffect)(void *effect);
    /* + other operations.. */
};

struct DelayClass {
    unsigned delay;
    struct effect_ops *ops;
};

struct FlangerClass {
    unsigned period;
    struct effect_ops *ops;
};

/* The actual effect functions are here
 * Pointers to the actual structure may be needed for effect-specific parameterization, etc.
 */
float flangerEffect(void *flanger)
{
   struct FlangerClass *this = flanger;
   /* mix signal delayed by this->period with original */
   return 0.0f;
}

float delayEffect(void *delay)
{
    struct DelayClass *this = delay;
    /* delay signal by this->delay */
    return 0.0f;
}

/* Instantiate and assign a "default" operation, if you want to */
static struct effect_ops flanger_operations = {
    .processEffect = flangerEffect,
};

static struct effect_ops delay_operations = {
    .processEffect = delayEffect,
};

int main()
{
    struct DelayClass delay     = {.delay = 10, .ops = &delay_operations};
    struct FlangerClass flanger = {.period = 1, .ops = &flanger_operations};
    /* ...then for your signal */
    flanger.ops->processEffect(&flanger);
    delay.ops->processEffect(&delay);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is interesting. I'm unfamiliar with this syntax "struct DelayClass delay     = {.delay = 10, .ops = &operations};
"  Could you please explain the dot syntax here.

Comment: C99 allows you to use the so called 'designated initializers' to initialize aggregate types (arrays, unions, structs). The syntax is `.member = expression`.

Comment: I think you could add pointer to implementing struct inside the interface struct as ”void * this”. That way you could pass the interface as parameter somewhere, and still use the functions

Answer (score 3):

You implement interfaces using structs of function pointers. You can then have the interface struct embedded in your data object struct and pass the interface pointer as first parameter of every interface member function. In that function you then get the pointer to your container class (which is specific to your implementation) using container_of () macro. Search for "container_of linux kernel" for an implementation. It is a very useful macro.