# Peace of code in C - static issue

Tags: c, methods, static

How to write this kind of code in C ??

```
public static Encoding GetEncoding (
    int codepage
)
```

Comment: You can't have objects in C but you can have pointers to data `struct`ures and everything is public. BTW everything is effectively `static` Are you thinking about C++? Are you trying to use JNI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, there is no access control and no `this`. So `public` and `static` are already the only way to do things.

You probably want the header (interface) file to contain the prototype

```
extern Encoding *GetEncoding ( int codepage );
```

and the source (implementation) file should have

```
Encoding *GetEncoding ( int codepage ) {
    return & masterEncodingList[ codepage ]; /* example implementation */
}
```

---

The header file might also define `Encoding`:

```
struct Encoding {
    const char *name;
    /* other fields */
};
```

and the source file might define the encodings

```
Encoding masterEncodingList[] = {
    { "Swahili", /* other fields */ },
    { "Portuguese", /* ... */ },
    /* ... */
};
```

Have, ah, fun!

Answer (score 1):

There is no public in C. Functions have external linkage by default unless you mark them static explicitly. It's a good idea to have a prototype visible for your function (probably in a header file) when using it, so as to avoid mismatched expectations between the caller and reality :-)

For example, the following would be valid C:

```
encoding.h:
    typedef void * Encoding;
    Encoding getEncoding (int);

encoding.c:
    #include "encoding.h"
    Encoding getEncoding (int codePage) {
        return 0;
    }
```

If your intent is to convert C++ (or other OO languages) code to C, there are ways to do it such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c/351745#351745), but it's not for the faint of heart :-) Especially if you're supporting the proper OO concepts like inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: True, but the closest thing in C to Java's "public" keyword is declaring the function in a header file.

Answer (score 1):

There are no formal methods in C, and the `static` modifier means something else.  There are also no access control modifiers.  So:

```
Encoding *GetEncoding (int codepage) {

}
```

In java, the return value would probably be an object reference, so in C you would use a `*pointer`.