# void* pointing to 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a struct:

```
struct foo
{
  void *param;
};

void main(){
  foo object;
}
```

I need to make object.param point to a dynamically allocated 2D array.

I know this will obviously *not* work:

```
//CASE 1
pixel **buf = (pixel**)malloc(16*sizeof(pixel*));
for(int i=0; i<16;i++)
   buf[i] = (pixel*)malloc(16*sizeof(pixel));

object.param = (void **)buf
```

This works:

```
//CASE 2
pixel buf[16][16];
object.param = (void *)buf;
```

My question is:

1. In case 2 why is `buf` interpreted as a pointer of type `pixel` (when in fact `buf` stores `pixel*`) which allows it to be cast to a `void*`?
2. How do I make case 1 work?

Comment: What is the definition of `pixel`?

Comment: `struct pixel
 {  int x; 
    int y;
 };`

Comment: Case 1 and 2 can both use `object.param = buf;`  The type `void *` is a generic pointer type and any other object pointer can be converted to it without using a cast.

Comment: Both cases are probably a bad idea , `struct foo` should also contain enough information to retrieve the initial type before the conversion to `void *`

Comment: foo object;   -> struct foo object;

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
int main(){
    struct foo object;

    struct pixel **buf = malloc(10*sizeof(struct pixel*));
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    buf[i] = malloc(10*sizeof(struct pixel));

    object.param = buf;
}
```

The casts weren't necessary, and because this is C you need to use `struct pixel` instead of `pixel`.

Answer (score 0):

The second case works because you can cast any pointer to `void*`.

For the same reason, the first case will work if you do `object.param = (void *)buf`, or `object.param = buf`, as @Iskar comments.

Comment: Actually, the casts are unnecessary because any other [object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10579981/696485) pointer can be converted to a void pointer without an explicit cast. C is not C++.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, a 2D array in C of type `foo[M][N]` is really a 1D array of M×N elements and has type `foo*`.  If you declare `foo[10][3] a; foo *p = a;` then `foo[i][j]` and `p[i*10+j]` mean exactly the same thing.