# Evaluating a function with reference parameters

Tags: c++, reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void swap1(T& a, T& b) {
    T c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
}

int main() {
    int n1 = 5;
    int n2 = 7;
    swap1(n1, n2);
    cout << n1 << " " << n2 << endl;

    int *p1 = &n1;
    int *p2 = &n2;
    swap1(*p1, *p2);
    cout << n1 << " "<< n2 << endl;
}
```

In many languages, when you call a function, you first evaluate its arguments, and then apply the function to the results of the evaluation.

If we follow this rule here however, `swap1(n1, n2)` and `swap1(*p1, *p2)` would both evaluate to `swap1(5, 7)` which makes no sense.

So, what are the rules of evaluation in this case? Also, what are the rules of evaluating a function in general in C++?

Comment: Inside the function, the arguments `a` and `b` ***references*** the *variables* `n1` and `n2` from the `main` function. You don't pass in the *values* of those variables. It doesn't matter that you use dereferenced pointers, since those pointers point to `n1` and `n2`.

Comment: Consider operation like `int n = 2; n++;` Are you going to insist it's equivalent to `2++`...? Hint: study differences between l-values and r-values, known since beginnings of C.

Comment: Evaluating an lvalue does NOT mean to access the stored value; the result of evaluating `*p1` is a designator of that memory location, not `5`.  Then when the function parameters are initialized: the effect of initializing a reference parameter with an lvalue expression, is to bind the reference to the expression (again, does not access the memory location)

Comment: I've always thought that n++ was just syntax sugar for n = n + 1 but I guess that's irrelevant to this?

Comment: @user52874 It's most definitely not syntactic sugar for that. The return value differs. The number of times `n` is evaluated differs. The `operator` function used when overloading the operation differs.

Comment: Very nice question, shows actual thought about the rules in play.

Comment: @M.M "the result of evaluating *p1 is a designator of that memory location". What is a designator? Is it the memory address?

Comment: @user52874 no, it's not an address. It's an abstract thing that means the memory location.

Comment: @M.M So the behavior this abstract thing depends on what you do with it? If you say `cout << *p1`, then its content is printed out. If you say `*p1 = 0`, then you set the content of this abstract thing to the value 0?

Also, is a designator the same as an object in C (region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values)? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579825/objects-in-c-language

Comment: The designator is not the object. It's an expression designating the object.   `*p1 = 0;` modifies the object. The designator lets us know which object to modify.

Comment: @M.M is there anywhere I can read more about designators? I can't seem to find anything about it on Google.

Comment: @user52874 See  C++14 [basic.lval]/1.1

Answer (score 2):

> In many languages, when you call a function, you first evaluate its arguments, and then apply the function to the results of the evaluation.

That is exactly what happens in C++ too. However, we have to analyse what "evaluating a function's arguments" actually means. In C++, it means "copy-initialising the parameter using the expression specified as the argument." The way to copy-initialise a C++ reference is to bind to the entity desginated by the initialiser. In the case of lvalue references (like in your `swap`), this means the initialiser must be an lvalue. `n1` is an lvalue, and so is `*p1`. Since the reference wants an lvalue, that's all the evaluation there is to do.

If the parameter was of value type (not a reference), the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion would be applied next to initialise the value. But since we're initialising a reference, this conversion does not happen.