# C supports basic class?

Tags: c, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you write object oriented code in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c)

Does C support simple class without polymorphism, inheritance etc.?

I need only definition of class and methods.

Answer (score 6):

C has no class concept on its own.

It is possible, however, to implement something like that:

```
struct stuff {
    void (*do_it)(void);
    void (*close)(void);
};

struct stuff new(void) {
    struct stuff ret;
    ret.do_it = ...;
    ret.close = ...;
    return ret;
}


int main() {
    struct stuff s = new();
    s.do_it();
    s.close();
}
```

Comment: @Linus Thanks, that was just as I intended.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a struct and store function-pointers in it.

Comment: It isn't very simple: I have to generate C code from another language (by Xtend) and without classes it is very difficult to emulate some construct of other language.

Answer (score 2):

C is not object oriented. So no. But it supports [structs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29)