# Is it possible to simulate object/instance methods in C?

Tags: c, oop

I'm aware that, because C isn't object oriented, the closest we can get to methods is using function pointers in a struct. This is just a thought exercise, but is it possible to have:

```
list.add(void* data)
```

*without passing in the list itself as a parameter*?

I know that:

```
list.add(list_t* list, void* data)
```

would be easy to implement, but is there any way, using whatever parts of C, to simulate a method in this way?

I recognize it's possible the answer is no, but please explain to me if you can! Thanks.

Comment: A more C++/Java-like way to implement OO in C is to add in every object a pointer to a structure defining its class that is where the pointers go.

Comment: You could get something syntactically close if your compiler supported nested functions. But syntactically only; it would still be horrible.

Comment: Your question is confused, because what you need is `ListClass.add(list, data)` or `list->class.add(list, data)` ... you don't want function pointers in every list node.

Comment: Also related, possibly useful reading: [Can you write object oriented code in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/351733)

Answer (score 6):

This is the prettiest syntax I got using **variadic macros** (C99):

```
#define call(obj, method, ...) ((obj).method(&(obj), __VA_ARGS__))
```

[usage (click for ideone)](http://ideone.com/Kb43wr):

```
struct class {
    int a;
    int (*method)(struct class* this, int b, int c);
};

int code(struct class* this, int b, int c) {
    return this->a*b+c;
}

struct class constructor(int a) {
    struct class result = {a, code};
    return result;
}

#define call(obj, method, ...) ((obj).method(&(obj), __VA_ARGS__))

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    struct class obj = constructor(10);
    int result = call(obj, method, 2, 3);
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about variadic macros, hence my uglier (and as it turns out, incorrect) answer. Still I wouldn't do the `&(obj)` part in the macro, since it won't allow calling methods on pointers, and having objects dynamically allocated is a very common case in C. Maybe it would be better to have just `(obj)` and have the programmer write `call(&obj, ...)` manually when the object is on the stack.

Comment: @JakubWasilewski: you call methods through pointers with `call(*ptr, method, args...)`

Comment: If you're going to have more than one method in a class, it makes sense to gather them into a vtable -- so it becomes `#define call(obj, method, ...) ((obj).vtab->method(&(obj), __VA_ARGS__))` and you define a single `struct class_vtable_t {...} class_vtable = {...}` object with the function pointers in it.

Comment: Variadic macros definitely seem to be on the right track, but I don't know if #defining a call() method is any better than just directly calling the function code(), without using the macro. Is there any way to use these macros to create the line 'int result = obj.method(2, 3);', which would be closer to real OO programming?

Comment: @Miguel re why not call `code()` directly: Conceptually, `main` doesn't know _how_ a method "method" is implemented in "obj", it only knows its name ("method") and signature. Technically, this achieves *dynamic dispatch*.

Comment: @Miguel re syntax: I can't see that `call(obj, method, 2, 3)` is any different from `obj->method(2, 3)` apart from aesthetics. Objective-C goes even more weird than that and it's still no less OO.

Answer (score 2):

Not only instance methods, but you can even have CLOS-style generic methods with the right library. [Laurent Deniau's COS library](https://github.com/CObjectSystem/COS) (also see paper: [[link]](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/45905934_The_C_Object_System_Using_C_as_a_High-Level_Object-Oriented_Language/file/79e415053141f86402.pdf)) provides a full OO system you can just `#include` and start using immediately; the method syntax is no heavier than any other function call.

It's apparently fast, too; the author claims to have gained a performance edge on similar code expressed in Objective-C (I'll take the claim itself with a pinch of salt, but even if they're comparable that's impressive).

Answer (score 1):

To emulate OO method calls, you need objects with class or vtable pointers. If your `list_t` contains, say, a `funcs` member that points to a struct containing function pointers, one of which is `add`, then your usage would be

```
list->funcs->add(list, data)
```

which you could capture in a variadic macro:

```
#define OO(obj, func, ...) (obj)->funcs->func(obj, __VA_ARGS__)

OO(list, add, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simple, you can implement struct member functions using the blocks language extension. Blogged [here](http://chrisbarrettnz.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/objects-in-c-using-blocks/).

You can use blocks to lambda-capture the associated struct, simulating the *this* pointer.

There's no virtual dispatch with this approach, so it's up to you whether you consider these true objects.