# Simulating Interfaces, Overriding Methods, Polymorphism and calling the overridden super method in C

Tags: c, interface, polymorphism, overriding, superclass

A static library that can receive any struct via `void *` and is able to access it's member variables whether an embedded struct or a pointer to a function.

It's guaranteed that a member variable which is an embedded struct will be there and is accessible via `super` and a member variable which is a pointer to a function will be available called `execute`.

**Question - (in short how to access underlying struct members using `void *` only)**

I guess it's related to generic programming, can we somewhow access the following via memory addresses or any other alternate way.
casting to specific structure is not available at compile time
struct will sure have an execute pointer function and super variable. Guaranteed.

```
// from src/library.c (someStruct a void *, casting to specific struct is not available)
someStruct->execute();
someStruct->super->execute();
```

**Attempt 1** [Reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/85450/How-to-access-structure-member-using-address-of-st)

```
struct Super *pointer = someStruct + 8; // works
pointer->execute(); // prints overridden method!

// how to access second member which is a pointer to function
```

Open to any form of solutions whether it's going low level to memory addresses to access each member or any other alternate way.

[Project Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ucuexprtpjf7avv/Poly.zip?dl=0)

---

**Expected Output:**

> overridden method!
>
> super method

---

**src/library.h**

```
#ifndef POLY_LIBRARY_H
#define POLY_LIBRARY_H

struct Library {
    void (*passSomeStruct)(void *someStruct);
};

struct Library *newLibrary();

#endif
```

**src/library.c**

```
#include "library.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

void passSomeStruct(void *someStruct) {

    // can we somewhow access the following via memory addresses or any other alternate way.
    // casting to specific structure is not available at compile time
    // struct will sure have an execute pointer function and super variable
      
      someStruct->execute();
      someStruct->super->execute();
}

struct Library *newLibrary() {
    struct Library *library = malloc(sizeof(struct Library));
    library->passSomeStruct = passSomeStruct;
    return library;
}
```

**src/super.h**

```
#ifndef POLY_SUPER_H
#define POLY_SUPER_H

struct Super {
    void (*execute)();
};

struct Super *newSuper();

#endif //POLY_SUPER_H
```

**src/super.c**

```
#include "super.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void execute() {
    printf("super method\n");
}

struct Super *newSuper() {
    struct Super *super = malloc(sizeof(struct Super));
    super->execute = execute;
    return super;
}
```

---

**Test**

**test/library_test.h**

```
#ifndef POLY_LIBRARY_TEST_H
#define POLY_LIBRARY_TEST_H

#endif //POLY_LIBRARY_TEST_H
```

**test/library_test.c**

```
#include "../src/library.h"
#include "temp.h"

int main() {
    struct Library *library = newLibrary();
    struct Temp *temp = newTemp();
    library->passSomeStruct(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

**test/temp.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_SUPER_H
#define TEST_SUPER_H

#include <stdlib.h>

struct Temp {
    struct Super *super;
    void (*execute)();
};

struct Temp *newTemp();

#endif //TEST_SUPER_H
```

**test/temp.c**

```
#include "temp.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../src/super.h"

static void execute() {
    printf("overridden method!\n");
}

struct Temp *newTemp() {
    struct Temp *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Temp));
    temp->super = newSuper();
    temp->execute = execute;
    return temp;
}
```

---

**MakeFile**

```
VPATH := src test

all: libTest

libTest: super.o library.o
    mkdir -p bin
    ar rcs bin/libTest $^

test: library_test
    ./library_test

library_test: library_test.o library.o super.o temp.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c %.h
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking a question?

Comment: yes, see the question section

Comment: The whole post is **a** question, what section are you talking about? The code comments in `void passSomeStruct(void *someStruct)`?

Comment: yes and I've added a section titled question as well.

Comment: So, you are trying to do OOP in C, right? There is this [book](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) by Axel Schreiner that goes deep in detail about this topic. I also like how the glib library solves this Problem with [GObject](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/GObject). I think your question is just to broad.

Comment: I guess the gist is how to access underlying member variables or function pointers of a struct through `void *` without casting.

Comment: yes I did go through the book but I still need help, I couldn't find a section on overriding method and calling super unless you can point or read the above comment about the gist. you may also download the project and execute yourself to understand. Run `make` and `make test`

Comment: the question is not broad, I've done 90% of it, it's this 10% that deals with handling `void *`, can you access members of a struct through a `void *`? that's all there's to the question. Don't let the length of the code scare you.

Comment: If you only have a `void` pointer and you don't have the real structure that you can cast the `void` pointer, I'm afraid you cannot do that. A possible way would be that you cast the `void` pointer to `char*`. If you know the byte layout that the compiler uses for your target instruction, then you could access the bytes directly through the casted `char*` pointer. But that would be portable at all.

Comment: yes, that's the part I need to know more, I don't know much about that domain, byte layout, casting to char* etc. At minimum it's guaranteed that each `void *` will have two members, one an embedded struct (real structure available and it's `struct Super` defined in super.h) and a pointer function (signature known, returns void and accepts void). Can you please write some code in `passSomeStruct` to do all that? I guess this part they call generic programming in c

Comment: and I'd also appreciate if you can provide some link that can help me understand more about programming using plain memory addresses

Comment: the C language does not have `polymorphism` nor `inheritance`,  Perhaps your confusing with C++

Comment: I know, that's why it says simulating, anyway the gist of the question is to access underlying members via `(void *)` without casting, can you do that, see `passSomeStruct` in library.c. If you can do that then polymorphism and inheritance can be simulated in C.

Comment: @Pablo see the section Attempt 1 please in my question.

Comment: @Pablo see my answer below, is this is what you were suggesting?

Comment: @App2015 more or less yes, but this is very fragile code, change a tiny bit in the structs and the whole thing blows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that I cannot give you a perfect example of how OOP should be done in
C, not of the top of my head in a couple of minutes anyway. There are other
threads here in Stack Overflow that cover this is in far more detail, like this
one:

[Can you write object-oriented code in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c)

I highly recommend that you read that thread, there are many good answers there.

I also recommend, that if you really want to use OOP in your code base, don't
write it yourself, it is very complex and would be very time consuming. In that
case I would recommend that you use [`GObject`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/) that is part of the code of
the [`glib`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.54/) library. I tell you all this because in the comments you say

> yes, that's the part I need to know more, I don't know much about that domain, byte layout, casting to `char*` etc.

and when it come to stuff like this, knowing these things is fundamental.

I'm going to give you a very brief example of what I meant in the comments about
the memory layout, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define TEND 0
#define TINT 1
#define TSTRING 2
#define TDOUBLE 3

typedef struct typeinfo {
    int type;
    size_t offset;
} TypeInfo;




typedef struct K1 {
    int a;
    int b;
    char c[32];
} K1;

void print_K1(K1 *obj)
{
    printf("K1: %d %s %d\n", obj->a, obj->c, obj->b);
}

TypeInfo *init_k1(K1 *obj, int a, int b, const char *c)
{
    TypeInfo *types = calloc(4, sizeof *types);

    obj->a = a;
    obj->b = b;
    strcpy(obj->c, c);

    // filling type info
    // we know the structure, we can provide this information
    types[0].type = TINT;
    types[0].offset = offsetof(K1, a);

    types[1].type = TINT;
    types[1].offset = offsetof(K1, b);

    types[2].type = TSTRING;
    types[2].offset = offsetof(K1, c);

    types[3].type = TEND;

    return types;
}

typedef struct K2 {
    int k;
    double o;
} K2;

void print_K2(K2 *obj)
{
    printf("K2: %d %lf\n", obj->k, obj->o);
}

TypeInfo *init_k2(K2 *obj, int k, double o)
{
    TypeInfo *types = calloc(3, sizeof *types);

    obj->k = k;
    obj->o = o;

    // filling type info
    // we know the structure, we can provide this information
    types[0].type = TINT;
    types[0].offset = offsetof(K2, k);

    types[1].type = TDOUBLE;
    types[1].offset = offsetof(K2, o);

    types[2].type = TEND;

    return types;
}



void somefunc(void *ptr, TypeInfo *types)
{
    char *base = ptr, *offset;

    while(1)
    {
        offset = base + types->offset;
        switch(types->type)
        {
            case TINT:
            {
                int *p = (int*) offset;
                *p *= -1;
                break;
            }

            case TSTRING:
            {
                char *p = offset;
                p[0] = ' ';
                break;
            }

            case TDOUBLE:
            {
                double *p = (double*) offset;
                *p *= 0.35;
            }

            case TEND:
                return;
        }

        types++;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    K1 k1;
    K2 k2;

    TypeInfo *t1, *t2;

    t1 = init_k1(&k1, 33, -23, "Hello Peter");
    print_K1(&k1);
    somefunc(&k1, t1);
    print_K1(&k1);

    t2 = init_k2(&k2, 112, 122.12);
    print_K2(&k2);
    somefunc(&k2, t2);
    print_K2(&k2);

    free(t1);
    free(t2);

    return 0;
}
```

I have two struct `K1` and `K2` with different members, that means their memory
layout is different. For `K1` and `K2` there are init functions that using the
helper struct `TypeInfo` store the offsets and types of the struct members of
their own class. This information is **known** to them, so they can construct
such a table of information. `offsetof` returns the offset of the field member
from the start of the structure type.

The function `somefunc` doesn't know anything about the structs, so it cannot
cast the `void` pointer to a pointer of the structs. However it gets a list of
types from the caller. This functions changes the sign for every `int` member,
replaces the first letter with an empty character for every string and
multiplies every double by `0.35`. Thanks to `types` it can get the members by
using the offset supplied by `types`.

The `main` function initializes one object of each struct, prints the original
state, calls `somefunc` with the object and the type information and prints the
objects again. In the output you can see that the values were change
accordingly.

**Output**

```
K1: 33 Hello Peter -23
K1: -33  ello Peter 23
K2: 112 122.120000
K2: -112 42.742000
```

While this might work, I don't think that this is an elegant solution. This is a
basic example but it could get very complicated when dealing with more complex
structs. This shows you how you can access the contents of a struct where you
only have a `void` pointer. But without the type information, this could not be
done. For that reason I encourge you to use some library that has already
implemented a typing system. `GObject` is very mature and widely use in GTK+ applications.
The Glib and GTK+ folks have been using that for years, so I would trust their
implementation over any self implemented solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it demystified, but I'm open to suggestions, can anyone improve this answer and make it better or explain to me what's going on in here?

It's some sort of magic number 8, that did the trick.

```
void passSomeStruct(void *someStruct) {
    struct Super *pointer = someStruct + 8; 
    pointer->execute(); // outputs "overridden method!"

    pointer = someStruct + 16; 
    pointer->execute(); // outputs "super method"
}
```

**Edit**

my struct definition, I'm wondering why `super` which is defined first is 16 offset and the method `execute` I defined is 8 offset, is memory allocated is in reverse and not in the order I defined them?

```
struct Temp {
    struct Super *super;
    void (*execute)();
};
```

Comment: The "magic" 8 is the offset of where you  `struct Super` is in memory in regards to the containing struct. The problem of this "magic" number is that if you later change the structure, for whatever reason, the offset might change and `passSomeStruct` becomes garbage. Read my answer where I explain that and give you recommendations of what you should use in a production project. Unless you do it for fun.

Comment: @Pablo does order matter? See my edit section for this answer please.

Comment: The order of the elements of the struct? Of course it does, the offsets are dependent on the order of the elements of the struct. That's what I meant with "change a little and the whole thing blows up". You change the order for some reason and the "magic" numbers become invalid. Look at the code in my answer, there you can change the order without having problems.