# Should I encapsulate slice and maps in Go? If so, how to do it?

Tags: go

I want to create a structure which will be accessible in other packages, but I don't want to allow modify this structure. In other languages this is archived by making all fields private and exposing only public getters.

Solution with getters works fine for all data types except slices and maps because returned slices and maps aren't copied by default so they can be modified. The only solution that I managed to figure out is to create new map/slice and assign all items in a loop but this introduce a lot of repetitive and ugly code, especially for large nested structures.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type OtherStruct struct {
    prop string
}

type Struct struct {
    prop map[string]OtherStruct
}

func (s Struct) Prop() map[string]OtherStruct {
    return s.prop
}

func (s Struct) Prop2() map[string]*OtherStruct {
    prop := make(map[string]*OtherStruct, 0)
    for k := range s.prop {
        v := s.prop[k]
        prop[k] = &v
    }

    return prop
}

func main() {
    var s Struct;

    // Simple getter
    s = Struct{make(map[string]OtherStruct, 0)}
    p1 := s.Prop()
    fmt.Println(s) // &{map[]}
    p1["something"] = OtherStruct{"test"}
    fmt.Println(s) // {map[something:{test}]}

    // Getter which copies map
    s = Struct{make(map[string]OtherStruct, 0)}
    p2 := s.Prop2()
    fmt.Println(s) // &{map[]}
    p2["something"] = &OtherStruct{"test"}
    fmt.Println(s) // &{map[]}
}
```

Is there any better way to encapsulate slices/maps in Go? Or maybe I shouldn't use encapsulation at all in Go and use different approach?

Comment: Make your "getters" and "setters" work on a pointer receiver. Or even better: Stop worrying.

Comment: Changing to a pointer receiver won't change anything. And I worry because I want to write good code.

Comment: For slices (if that's what you mean by array) you can use the builtin `copy` function. For maps using a for loop to create a copy, as you are already doing, is the the way to go. Alternatively wrap your map/slice in a struct that provides only getters for its *elements*, not the whole value as you're doing in your example.

Comment: "because I want to write good code" you should write good Go code not good Java code.

Comment: @Volker arguably, getters are best implemented on a value receiver... that said: 100% agree on the good Go code vs Java code comment :P

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for your response. If there are no other solutions I'll probably stuck with my current solution because it makes iterating easier.

Comment: @Volker So this is why I asked about different approaches at the end of my question. If you have some good ideas I will be grateful if you tell something about them. Answers like "it's bad because it's bad" aren't too helpful :/

Comment: Any question tagged oop & go is off to a bad start; Go is not object-oriented.

Comment: @Adrian You should read what authors of Go says about this topic. Encapsulation is term from OOP and authors od Go says it is at least partially object oriented so in my opinion OOP tag fits here.

Comment: I have read a lot of what the Go authors have said about the topic, though without a link I have no idea what you're referring to specifically. Go is not what most would consider object-oriented. It has no classes, no objects, no inheritance, and no polymorphism outside of interfaces. Typical OOP patterns (such as getters/setters) are unidiomatic in Go. Generally, attempts at OOP in Go lead to frustration and poor quality.

Comment: I'm referring to the FAQ on the Go official website. You don't need Java like support in the language to do OOP, you can even write object oriented code in C. There was a great discussion about it on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c

Comment: I got few downvotes I'm not sure what's wrong with my question. It's not duplicated and I think it's common problem for newcomers. I'd be grateful for any feedback that I can learn from to help me improve my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning slice or map values is idiomatic Go. The user of your package will know how those data structures work in Go.

In your example, the user of `Struct` should know that adding a new entry into the returned map would reflect for any other user of the same map.

```
// Simple getter
s = Struct{make(map[string]OtherStruct, 0)}
p1 := s.Prop()
fmt.Println(s) // &{map[]}
p1["something"] = OtherStruct{"test"}
fmt.Println(s) // {map[something:{test}]}
```

You should worry about such things only in case of concurrency. That is, when multiple goroutines are accessing, and possibly changing, the elements inside your slice or map.

Comment: So maybe it will be better idea to remove all getters and just point in a documentation, that these structures shouldn't be modified?

Comment: I think your are right. Getters and setters are not common in Go, AFAIK. So, you can get rid of your getter, unless you have to satisfy an interface with that data structure. 
IMHO, documentation is optional.